# How to make clickable links and cross-references in pdfs produced by LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, indexing, links

How can I make things link url references, my index, table of contents, and cross references clickable links in documents produced by LaTeX? I generally use pdflatex to produce my documents.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The [hyperref package](https://texdoc.org/serve/hyperref/1) does all of these things. you may need to include it with options like <strike>backlinks</strike>`backref` to get back references, but it does everything you need.

Comment: Once you start using `hyperref`, you might well ask yourself: How can I [remove the ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/4012)? For even more issues regarding this package, check out the top questions tagged with {[tag:hyperref]}.

Comment: The documentation is pretty voluminous.  To just create a simple hyperlink, this worked for me: `\usepackage{hyperref}` at the top after the other usepackages, and `\href{url}{linktext}` where I want to put a link.

Comment: The option is called `backref`, not `backlinks`.

Comment: @doncherry Your link to the *hyperref* resource gives a 403 only.

Comment: @malte It wasn’t me who posted that link, but I replaced it with a working one anyway ;). Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This link is now broken