# A bad result with the soulutf8 package

Tags: packages

When I combine `\textsl` `\textbf` and `\hl` from the `soulutf8` package, the result is ugly. Some letters are degraded. By zooming or printing you can see that with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\begin{document}

\large

\textsl{\textbf{{application module morphisme}}}     % Correct

\textsl{\textbf{\hl{application module morphisme}}}  % Ugly!
%                    —  — —       —  —   —

\end{document}
```

I'm very disappointed with this. Could you help me please?

[image]

closer look:

[image]

oops.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx You can indent code blocks by four spaces (or use the `{}` button) and similarly use backticks for `inline code`.

Answer (score 3):

`\hl` colors the bounding box of the chars one syllable by one. These boxes are rectangles, and so the box of a following char can overlap the precedent char. You can avoid it by using `\mbox`:

```
\textsl{\textbf{\hl{\mbox{application} \mbox{module} \mbox{morphisme}}}}
```

-- at the cost that no hyphenation is possible.

You could also try to use tikz as in the answer here
[Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex/6029#6029)

Comment: It's better! But the 'e' of module are 'cutted' with this code.

Comment: That is the color of the space which overlaps, you could add a small amount of space (`\,`) after the e.