# Vertical line next to a block, across page breaks

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking

I'd like to mark examples, in an `example` environment in the text by drawing a vertical bar along the margin. I found a piece of code that uses the `framed` package to do this, but since the content of the environment in a box, this doesn't break across pages.

To show the example will continue on the next page, the line should extend vertically a bit further before/after the page break. That shouldn't be a problem using tikz, if one manages to place coordinates at the first/last lines of the environment and at the lines before/after each page break. It looks like [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24279/2356) was working on something like this, but I haven't found if that's ended up in a package by now…

In my case, I need support for at most one page break per environment.

Comment: mdframed allows frames with page breaking and I believe can be customised to only put the frame on one side if that is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Davis Carlisle** mentions in a comment, the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package offers you a nice possibile solution, through its `\newmdtheoremenv` command; a little example interacting with one theorem style from `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newmdtheoremenv[
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt,
  leftmargin=-13pt,
  splitbottomskip=2ex,
  splittopskip=3ex,
  linecolor={cyan!80!black},
  topline=false,
  leftline=true,
  bottomline=false,
  rightline=false,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  innerlinewidth=3pt
  font=\normalfont
]{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an adaptation for this so that the vertical line doesn't extend past the last line and start above the first line of each page?