# Side margin text and brace across multiple pages

Tags: marginpar, braces

hopefully a simple question to ask, not sure about the answer...

Given the MWEs

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\BrText[2]{%
\par\smallskip
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{$\text{#1}\left\{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
#2
\end{minipage}
\right.\nulldelimiterspace=0pt$}\par\smallskip
}    

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\BrText{Some text}{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

in [Brace and text in side margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33993/brace-and-text-in-side-margin/33998#33998), with particular attention to Medina's answer only because it seems to be the most foundational, i.e., without extra packages, I was hoping someone could extend this solution so that braces and margin text could cross pages.

A small caveat would be to also have the margin text wrap but I think I have that figured out with this:

```
\def\rightwidewidth{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newcommand\BrText[2]{%
\par\smallskip
%   \noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{$\text{#1}\left\{
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{$\begin{minipage}{\rightwidewidth}#1\end{minipage}\left\{%0.1\textwidth
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
#2
\end{minipage}
\right.\nulldelimiterspace=0pt$}\par\smallskip
}
```

Though I was told this was not great - on my even pages it is right up against the edge of the page, odd pages are fine - maybe someone could help improve it?

For what its worth, I typically use amsart document class and lualatex engine...

**addendum**

After looking around more, e.g., [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text?lq=1), [Vertical line next to a block, across page breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107374/vertical-line-next-to-a-block-across-page-breaks), and [create a framed environment for a margin note](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120224/create-a-framed-environment-for-a-margin-note/120253#120253), I've realized that **any** method would be spectacular for me - regardless of the need for new packages. Thanks!

Comment: I think I attempted to answer a question that 
@GonzaloMedina had posted which had braces spanning pages, but can't seem to find it.