# Highlight some words of a beamer

Tags: beamer, highlighting

If I want to highlight some words of following frame:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Paragraphs of Text}
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida. Morbi sed tortor erat, nec interdum arcu. Sed id lorem       lectus. Quisque viverra augue id sem ornare non aliquam nibh tristique. Aenean in ligula nisl. Nulla sed tellus ipsum. Donec vestibulum ligula non lorem vulputate fermentum accumsan neque mollis.\\~\\

Sed diam enim, sagittis nec condimentum sit amet, ullamcorper sit amet libero. Aliquam vel dui orci, a porta odio. Nullam id suscipit ipsum. Aenean lobortis commodo sem, ut commodo leo gravida vitae. Pellentesque vehicula ante iaculis arcu pretium rutrum eget sit amet purus. Integer ornare nulla quis neque ultrices lobortis. Vestibulum ultrices tincidunt libero, quis commodo erat ullamcorper id.
\end{frame}
```

what should I do?

Comment: Is `\alert{hi!}` what you are looking for?

Comment: @moewe : dose there have `\begin{alert} \end{alert}` this things

Comment: There is also `\begin{alertenv}trallllalllala\end{alertenv}`, use the macro for short text and the environment for paragraphs or longer texts.

Comment: @moewe is there a command that works in beamer that does traditional yellow-background highlighting?

Comment: @dbliss See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136742/35864 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/35864 depending on the complexity you need. If none of those are what you want and you can't find anything else on this site, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\alert{foo}` to highlight a short portion of text.
For longer paragraphs the `alertenv` environment is more apt (though `\alert{}` does not complain when fed an argument containing a new paragraph); use it as follows

```
\begin{alertenv}
  foo and indeed bar
\end{alertenv}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Quite Some Text}
  The following short text will be \alert{highlighted with \texttt{alert}}, while this is not.  

  \begin{alertenv}
    We can highlight entire paragraphs with the \texttt{alertenv} environment.

    See, that was a paragraph.
  \end{alertenv}

  Note though that \alert{\texttt{alert} does not complain when fed a paragraph.

  See, a new paragraph.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]