# Changing background color of text in Latex

Tags: color, backgrounds, text-decorations, text-manipulation

How can I make change a text background in LaTeX?
For example using Latex code

```
\textsc{Extra Curricular Achievements}\
```

I get
[image]

However, I want the background of this heading to be changed so that it looks like this:-
[image]

I want the background to be extended to the right upto line break.
Please ignore the underline in the previous image. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I prefer using `tcolorbox` thinking that in future you may want the background to be fashionable. I have given many options (which are not needed for this particular case) in the `tcbset` so that you can play with them to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    frame code={},
    center title,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    colback=gray!70,
    colframe=white,
    width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
    enlarge left by=0mm,
    boxsep=5pt,
    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\textsc{Extra Curricular Achievements}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another option using `framed` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{180,180,180}
\begin{document}
\begin{snugshade*}
\noindent\textsc{Extra Curricular Achievements}
\end{snugshade*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without extra packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{150,150,150}
\begin{document}
\noindent\colorbox{shadecolor}
{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textsc{Extra Curricular Achievements}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And convert it in to a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{150,150,150}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\par\noindent\colorbox{shadecolor}
{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\mybox{\textsc{Extra Curricular Achievements}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks .. btw using the tcbset approach, what can be done to remove the surrouding box .

Comment: @sairajat Sorry which box? I don't follow.

Comment: the surrounding purple colored box . sorry for late reply. did it myself . Thanks anyways .. :)

Comment: @sairajat Never mind. That is my style of putting a picture on this site. If you run my code, you won't get it :-)

Comment: Can we apply this to complete page?

Answer (score 249):

I know this question has been answered very extensively. But not what I wanted or thought was the question based on the title. Therefore if others get in here looking for a possibility for colouring behind a word than this snippet is much easier:

`\colorbox{blue!30}{blue}`

or

`\textcolor{blue!30}{blue}`

resulting in:

[image: Color result of the above commands]

This is possible by only adding `\usepackage{xcolor}`. Just some extra info :)

**Colour Several Lines**
It is correct that the above methods does not work for several lines, if you to be more than one line you can do:

`{\color{green} the text you want to write}`

This can however also be wrapped in a function so it is easier to use several places during edits, e.g., for colouring new text or whatever:

`\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\color{green}[added]:#1}}`

Comment: text inside `\colorbox` can not be split into several lines if it is too long. So the macro is most suited for coloring a few words. If you want to color several sentences which spread across several lines, it is better to use [`soul`](http://texblog.org/2015/05/20/using-colors-in-a-latex-document/)

Comment: @Hao if you have a minimal example with the usings, post it or edit the answer that would be cool! :)

Comment: The given link have some illustrating examples about how to use the `soul` package.

Comment: sorry for off-topic, but hard to resist: I like how LaTeX is not easy at all -- you need to use `soul` to put some colour behind some text.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, no immense amount of packages, no huge newcommands, simply the colorbox. Thanks mate!

Comment: This example would have taken me fewer seconds to parse if you replaced the text "{blue}" with some other text. :)

Comment: @CPBL it has to be an extra challenge :D

Comment: What do the ! and 30 represent?

Comment: @mpr it is a fraction of the colour.

Comment: @jdhao added method for colouring several lines without using soul, had forgot it when you wrote :D

Comment: @xealits you do not need to use `soul`

Comment: @JTIM, the `\color{}` command will only color the text, not the text background.

Comment: @jdhao The link you posted about `soul`gives me the impression you can not have different background colours in the same document. Is that correct?

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson, It is possible. You can use groups to achieve what you want (in the group, use `\sethlcolor` to change color).

Comment: Bare in mind that the `\hl` command does not accept diacritics by default (see [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/soul/soul.pdf), section 5.1).

Comment: Plus, the thing with the `soul` package is that the margin around the text is minimal. In order to get something similar to the `xcolor` boxes, there is a way to add more top and bottom margin, redefining the correct leaders, like with `\def\SOUL@ulleaders{\leaders\hrule\@depth 1ex\@height 2.5ex\relax}`, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5988/117801). Nevertheless, I cannot find how to add left and right margin to it.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to the last comment. One can use the `minipage' environment to extend over several lines:

```
\colorbox{blue!10}{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\color{RoyalBlue} 

One line.

Another line.

The final line.
\end{minipage}
}
```