# Formatting text the same way knitr formats code, but outside of chunks

Tags: knitr, sweave

Back when I was using sweave, I could make my inline code look like R code by using `\texttt{whatever}` or `\verb@whatever@`.  I am trying out knitr, and the format of the code chunks sure is pretty.  But how do I get the format of the inline code to match the code chunks?  Mostly I want to say things like

The \someformattingcommand{lm} function fits linear regression models $y = X'\beta+\epsilon$

What is that formatting command?

Comment: Have you considered posting this question on the SO site for R?

Comment: @lawyeR what site is that?

Comment: What exactly do you want for your inline code? Using the same font and background as the code chunks, or do you want the syntax highlighting too?

Comment: @Tyler.  I realize I have bookmarked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r  and think of that as a site.

Comment: @Tyler  Syntax highlighting would be more informative for readers, if that is possible.  Tx

Comment: @Tyler just the font and highlighting.  Though if the background is easy to do or not do, such an answer might be good for posterity.

Comment: The font should just be `\texttt{}` I think. I've looked around and I don't know if you can get the syntax highlighting outside of a code block (which is provided via the `listings` package). `tcolorbox` allows you to change the background color inline, that might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136742/changing-background-color-of-text-in-latex?rq=1