# Wrapping text in a fcolorbox?

Tags: formatting

I'm using package "color" to have a green text box with black text, and my
code is -

```
\textbf{\fcolorbox{black}{green!30}{black text on a boxed green background}}
```

How can I get it to wrap lines please?

If it can't wrap with 'fcolorbox', what command would have the same effect and would wrap please?

Comment: You want to look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: If you want this coloured box to wrap inside the text just like other normal text, then you're probably interested in [Cool text highlighting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/5764) ((duplicate))

Comment: Thanks @Werner, I knew I answered some Q like this before but couldn't find it through the search. Not that my answer is the accepted one...

Comment: @boudiccas: The `soul` and `ulem` packages were written to highlight (underline, background color, etc.) flowing text and might do something similar what you want. Don't think they can create *exactly* the same style like `\fcolorbox`, through.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest one of my favourite packages: `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% A new `\tcbox` command



\newtcbox{\highlight}[0]{boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,right=0pt,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,colback=green,width=6cm}


\begin{document}

\highlight{black text on a boxed green background}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=6cm,colback=green]
black text on a boxed green background
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=6cm,colback=green,boxrule=5pt]
black text on a boxed green background
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=6cm,colback=green,arc=0pt,auto outer arc]
black text on a boxed green background
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But this isn't really feasible for just boxing and highlighting words or sentences as part of a paragraph.

Comment: @boudiccas: At what point in your post did you mention the highlighting? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer in comments on my answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Those comments were made **after** I posted my solution ;-)

Comment: and after mine:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Nevermind: You got my +1 anyway ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`\fcolorbox` is like `\fbox` or `\mbox` and makes a horizontal (LR) box, so you need

```
\textbf{\fcolorbox{black}{green!30}{%
   \parbox{3cm}{black text on a boxed green background}}}
```

replacing `3cm` by whatever width you need.

Comment: So I can't use it as an item in a sentence then? Like this ``In some places you may see a little \textbf{\fcolorbox{black}{green!30}{black text on a boxed green background}} round a word or two, these show that they are a common side-effect, ``

Comment: @boudiccas no (you could not use `\fbox` in that way either) if you want coloured highlighting within a paragraph look at `ulem` or `soul` packages

Comment: I'm looking for commands that will give me red, green, blue or yellow boxes, and neither package seem to be able to do it. Any other ideas please?