# Need linebreak when \fbox exceeds the text area

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

Need to align a "fbox", when exceeds the text area.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Blah \fbox{Text within box in horizontal line} Blah ...

Blah \fbox{Text within box in horizontal line breaking if exceeds text area} Blah ... 

\end{document}
```

While using `\fbox`, getting output like below:

[image]

Required output:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A `\fbox` does not provide `linebreaks, but a `\parbox` will do, however, it doesn't have a frame

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex/

Comment: Thanks, `parbox` require width and treat as separate box not align with my required output.

Comment: can we achieve this without using **[tikz]** package...