# Underlined math in a Beamer presentation: felt-tip marker underlining

Tags: beamer

I am composing a Beamer presentation, and I would like to underline some mathematical entities for emphasis.

I am aware of the ulem package, however for a presentation I would like something more visually pleasing, and I was thinking about a felt-tip marker effect, bold and slightly irregular, along these lines:

[image: Example 1]

or also

[image: Example 2]

I must be able to underline just parts of a mathematical expression.

Is there any package I can use to achieve such an effect?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/

Comment: Well, that's an excellent starting point! Thank you very much!