# How to display highlighted text generated by user command properly?

Tags: line-breaking, highlighting, backgrounds, soul, colorbox

I want to highlight some things to do or alternative words/phrases for future refinement in a draft.

I have tried to highlight text with `\hl` in soul package or `\colorbox` in xcolor package.
But `\colorbox` is not able to detect line breaks automatically, while `\hl` always results in compilation errors when there are user commands.

I have tried to add curly braces around the user command, but it didn't work.

I have tried to use `\mbox` to wrap the command, but the result is the same as `\colorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\reftab}[1]{\mbox{Table \ref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\reftabb}[1]{Table \ref{#1}}

\soulregister{\reftab}{1}
\soulregister{\reftabb}{1}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{tab \label{tab1}}
    \end{table}

    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa \hl{{\reftab{tab1}}}

    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}

    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa \hl{\mbox{\reftabb{tab1}}}

\end{document}
```

[image: overflow]

The picture above shows that the highlighted text is out of margin (the width of the line is text width), is it possible to make it wrap properly?

Even with microtype package, the output is still not desirable.

[image: overlow2]

Comment: Line breaking looks for hyphen points to assist it.  There are few in your example.  You can force valid linebreaking with `\sloppy` or the `sloppypar` environment, but it comes at the expense of excessive inter-word spacing.  The overfull box is a warning, perhaps, to restructure your document.

Comment: I have tried to use microtype package which works well in normal cases, but it will fail here if the highlighted text is long. @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: I would suspect It is because the act of highlighting breaks the hyphen-ability of the content.  In that case, your available hyphen points become greatly diminished.

Comment: I added another example with enough available hyphen points. It works fine without the `\mbox` when there is no user command. @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: An `\mbox` is definitely without hyphens, so that won't help.

Comment: Concerning you custom commands: You might want to have a look at the cleveref package. With that you can automatically insert `Table` etc.

Comment: maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @samcarter . I have tried the most voted answer in that question only to find out that it is based on soul package which fails either. But actually Martin Scharrer's answer (which is overlooked by myself earlier) will solve this question.