# Excess space surrounding highlighted text in modified soul's hl command

Tags: soul

In [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex), Gumbo offered, in a comment to Caramdir's answer, `\hlc`, a modification of `soul`'s `\hl` to allow choosing the highlighting color on the fly.

`\hlc`, though, leaves excess space around the highlighted text, particularly before but also after.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }
\begin{document}
In the source there is\hlc[yellow]{no space}between highlighted-surrounding text.
\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image: Excess Space]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points:

1. You had excess spaces *within* your macro definition, notably upon entry, upon exit and also just prior to `\hl`.  There are times when spaces in a macro definition have no effect, for example in math mode, or trailing the name of a macro are two notable examples.  However, in general, spaces in a macro definition are translated as spaces in the output.  This is where your spurious spaces arose, and
2. I added `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces` to the definition, to remove spaces that surround the `\hlc` invocation, as well.  You may not want those in your actual definition, but it is to show how the macro can reach outside of itself to also remove *external* surrounding spaces.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\unskip{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
In the source there is \hlc[yellow]{no space} between highlighted-surrounding text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A perfect answer: answers the question and explains why. Thanks

Comment: @schremmer (I will parenthetically add that this is the reason you will see `%` signs at the end of each line of a multi-line macro definition... the `%` eats the spurious space that would otherwise be introduced)

Comment: Ah! I have "always" dutifully ended each line in my preamble with a % (removed it for the question here!) but had no idea why! Now I know. :-)) Thanks again.

Comment: @schremmer In general, not all preamble lines need the `%`, only those that are inside of macro definitions, or those in the middle of a multi-line argument where spaces are not intended.  But I'm happy to see the "light bulb go on."  Learn more at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines