# Modified soul command \hl will not accept \boldsymbol

Tags: soul

In [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex), Gumbo offered, in a comment to Caramdir's answer, \hlc, a modification of soul's \hl to allow choosing the highlighting color on the fly. \hlc accepts `$2$` as argument but will not accept `\boldsymbol{$2$}`, complaining that `Argument of \boldsymbol has an extra }.` When I register the command `\boldsymbol` with `soul`,  see the documentation of soul "Adding font commands" (page 15), nothing at all happens.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister{\boldsymbol}{1}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}
\begin{document}
A. \boldsymbol{$2$}

B. \hlc[yellow]{$2$}

C. \hlc[yellow]{\textbf{Two}}

%D. \hlc[yellow]{\boldsymbol{$2$}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$\boldsymbol{2}$`?

Comment: @egreg It sure should---and it works. Why didn't you make it an answer I could accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no issue if I use the correct syntax:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}

\begin{document}
A. $\boldsymbol{2}$

B. \hlc[yellow]{$2$}

C. \hlc[yellow]{\textbf{Two}}

D. \hlc[red]{$\boldsymbol{2}$}

E. \hlc{$\boldsymbol{2}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]