# Tcolorbox: breakable inlined box

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox

I'd like to have a breakable inlined box in order to emphasis some text. Any idea how to do that, if possible with tcolorbox?

Thanks!

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % To switch to the T1 encoding
\usepackage{lmodern} % To switch to Latin Modern
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent Base text:\\
\noindent\rule{4cm}{1pt}\\
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
  Hello I would like to have a breakable tcbox in order to have a nice text.
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm}
\noindent With box (no break ??):\\
\noindent\rule{4cm}{1pt}\\
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
  Hello \tcbox[enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,breakable,colback=red!5!white,bottom=0pt,top=0pt,right=0pt,left=0pt,
    colframe=red!75!black]{I would like to have a breakable tcbox} in order to have a nice text.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It won't with tcolorbox. You would need some code that marks the begin and the end and then calculates the pathes, that's not an easy task. Check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: thanks for the links, it's very interesting but I can't find how to adapt it to tcbox, partly because I don't know how to go from tikz marquers to tcbox position…

Comment: @tobiasBora See [this post](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/223#issuecomment-1472734737) from the tcolorbox Github page

Comment: @mbert cool trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Simply select the mode `capture=minipage` in the options (see page 94 of manual 4.14).

I loaded the `showframe` package in order to visualize the margins.

[image: box]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % To switch to the T1 encoding
\usepackage{lmodern} % To switch to Latin Modern
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent Base text:\\
\noindent\rule{4cm}{1pt}\\
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
  Hello I would like to have a breakable tcbox in order to have a nice text.
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm}
\noindent With box (no break ??):\\
\noindent\rule{4cm}{1pt}\\
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
  Hello \tcbox[capture=minipage,enhanced,tcbox raise base,breakable,colback=red!5!white,bottom=0pt,top=0pt,right=0pt,left=0pt,
    colframe=red!75!black]{I would like to have a breakable tcbox} in order to have a nice text.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for, as I would like to keep the box as "inline", so in my example I'd the words "I would like" to stay,on the first line, exactly like in the first example. I just want to add a box around, that would "break" in several lines. A way to proceed would be to create three tcboxes, and set the first one with sharp right angles, the second box on the next line with all the angles sharp, and the last box on the last line and third line would have the left angles sharp. Of course this method is ugly.

Comment: @tobiasBora You must therefore do as indicated by Ulrike Fischer in her commentary.