# Inline DeclareTotalTCBox Using tColorBox

Tags: line-breaking, tcolorbox

My goal is to have inline code embedded in text using `\DeclareTotalTCBox`. The problem is that the box is not breakable (even though I used the `breakable` option). I looked at the [manual (v 4.20)](http://ctan.mirror.colo-serv.net/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) page 449, but I wasn't able to fix the problem. Any suggestions are welcomed! Thank you.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[most, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\inline}{v}{ 
    nobeforeafter,
    breakable,
    tcbox raise = -4pt,
    top         = 0pt,
    bottom      = 0pt,
    left        = 0pt,
    right       = 0pt,
    colback     = lightgray,
    colframe    = black,
}{\lstinline[basicstyle = \scriptsize\color{red}\tt]^#1^}

\begin{document}
Here is some random text filling the line for my problem to appear \inline{inline code inserted}
and now, the line ended.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `breakable` option in `tcolorbox` is intended to break boxes across pages, not from one line to the next. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459770/tcolorbox-breakable-inlined-box (actually it's a duplicate, I didn't mark it as duplicate because that question does not have a solution for the problem other than "it can't be done").

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have already seen the question you linked but it doesn't solve my problem as you suggested.

Comment: Package `soul` provides a command to highlight text which respect end of line breaks, but it won't draw border lines to highlighted text. As an alternative, you could try to adapt solutions in [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/1952)