# Cross-line inline tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, soul

As shown in the following example, underlining a cross-line sentence can be easily done by `\ul` via `soul.sty`. Can a cross-line sentence be `tcolorbox`ed automatically in a similar way?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
In order to show the expected result, allow me to add a few words here.
\ul{This is a cross-line long sentence.} Underlining a cross-line sentence is easy.

In order to show the expected result, allow me to add a few words here.
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black, right=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt, on line, hbox, sharp corners=east]
    This is a cross-line
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black, left=0pt,
    leftrule=0pt, on line, hbox, sharp corners=west]
    long sentence.
\end{tcolorbox}
Can a cross-line sentence be automatically tcolorboxed this way?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Tcolorbox: breakable inlined box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459770/134144)  and [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/134144)

Comment: @leandriis, Thanks for the pointers. I did check related questions and answers (including these two) before posting my question.

Comment: Since you already went through the construction of the two boxes with the mirrored corners, adding `\ul{..}`  inside is the simplest solution!

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125319/89417 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251182/box-highlighting-of-text-with-rounded-corners-soul-based/363828 that may come close. Both don't have the outline but that might be considered an advantage given that the lines in your example end up very far apart due to the height of the tcolorbox.

Comment: @SimonDispa, Great. I will think about your suggestion.

Comment: Marijn, Yes, they are pretty close. But I would like to exploit the advantage of tcolorbox that supports many fancy features.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using [`soulpos`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/soulpos) with tcolorbox. It was adapted from muzimuzhi's [post](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/223#issuecomment-1472734737) on tcolorbox's Github page, so all credit goes to them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\colorlet{ul}{red}
\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{
  on line,
  arc=1pt, outer arc=2pt,
  colback=ul!5!white, colframe=ul!75!black,
  boxsep=0pt, left=1pt, right=-0.5pt, top=2pt, bottom=1pt,
  boxrule=0pt, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt, #1
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myul[1][red]{%
  \UseName{str_if_eq:nnF}{#1}{red}{\colorlet{ul}{#1}}%
  \myul@}

\ulposdef\myul@[xoffset-start=1pt]{%
    \ifulstarttype{0}%
        {\tcbset{ULsiderule/.append style={leftrule=1pt}}}%
        {\tcbset{ULsiderule/.append style={leftrule=0pt,sharp corners=west}}}%
    \ifulendtype{0}%
        {\tcbset{ULsiderule/.append style={rightrule=1pt}}}%
        {\tcbset{ULsiderule/.append style={rightrule=0pt,sharp corners=east}}}%
    \mybox[ULsiderule]{\vphantom{Ap}\rule{\ulwidth}{0pt}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In order to show the expected result, allow me to add a few words here. \ul{This is a cross-line long sentence.} Can a cross-line sentence be automatically tcolorboxed this way?

In order to show the expected result, allow me to add a few words here. \myul{This is a cross-line long sentence.} Can a cross-line sentence be automatically tcolorboxed this way?

\begin{multicols}{2}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \newcolumn
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur \myul{adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore} et dolore
  \myul[green]{magna aliqua.}
\end{multicols}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc facilisis vitae massa nec cursus. Fusce faucibus gravida dolor. Cras egestas eget nulla ut consequat. Nulla eu mi at mauris feugiat ornare. \myul[orange]{Etiam a efficitur sem, et scelerisque massa. Sed ipsum justo, posuere vitae leo vitae, fermentum dictum lacus.} Morbi et ipsum vel neque congue elementum. In dolor orci, hendrerit vitae sagittis sit amet, pellentesque a magna.
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

You can change the options in `\mybox` to suit your needs.