# How to make a realistic highlighting

Tags: highlighting, soul

I'm using `\hl{}` from `soul`  package to highlight some words in my document. However, I'd like a "realistic" highlighting, simulating the result of a "manual" note: a not-so-regular rectangle with "waves" here and there.

I think a long time ago I saw something like that here in StackExchange but I could't find it.

### Edit

Yes, this is a duplicate of [Color Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex). I can't understand all the code but it is what I need. Just one more thing: is there a way to recreate the darker spot corresponding to the point where the highlighter is removed from the paper, like in the (exaggerated) image?

[image]

I don't really need it but it would make the document look more hand-drawn.

Comment: I am sorry, but what is "realistic" highlighting? Can post an example?

Comment: I mean a hand-drawn-looking highlighting, like the one I just added in the question.

Comment: You may also have a look at my `soulpos`.