# How to break long text in black box in tcolorbox?

Tags: line-breaking, tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{ 
    boxsep=4pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
    colframe=white,colback=black,  
    highlight math style={enhanced}
}
\begin{document}
        \noindent\tcbox{\textcolor{white}{Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello }}
\end{document}
```

I want make black rounded rectangle textbox with white text inside. After I search in tex.stackexchange.com, I found code above. But, if the text is too long, it cannot break into next line. How to break it?

[image]

**NOTE:**

I want the box is rounded rectangle and no white space between one line into next line.

Comment: Maybe you find something here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/263192

Comment: Like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640431/1952. You have to use a `tcolorbox` instead of a `tcbox`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

It's a `tcolorbox` instead of a `tcbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{ 
    boxsep=4pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
    colframe=white,colback=black,  
    highlight math style={enhanced}
}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tcolorbox}[colupper=white]Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello 
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `soul` package for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\sethlcolor{black}

\begin{document}
        \noindent{\color{white}\hl{Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello }}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the box is rounded rectangle and no white space between one line into next line.

Answer (score 0):

With minipage

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \tcbset{ 
        boxsep=4pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        colframe=white,colback=black,  
        highlight math style={enhanced}
    }
    \begin{document}
    \noindent\tcbox{%
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \textcolor{white}{Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello }
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \end{document}
```