# Remove vertical space between top box and first line text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\round[2]{\par
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[draw = #1, fill = #1, rectangle, rounded corners, 
        minimum size = 5.5mm, text = white, text width = \textwidth](char){#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}\par%
}%
\begin{document}
    \round{black}{\begin{center}
        \textbf{Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello}
    \end{center}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why there is vertical space between top box and first line text?

How to remove it?

I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be assumed, that in all `\round` boxes text had to be centered. If this assumption holds, than you can text in node center by node style option `align=center`. Similarly you can define, that text be in boldface:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\round[2]{\par
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node[draw=#1, fill=#1, rounded corners, , 
          font=\bfseries, text = white,
          text width=\textwidth -
                      2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
          align=center
          ] (char)  {#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}\par%
}%
\begin{document}
    \round{black}{\bfseries
Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
                }
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout).

Answer (score 3):

As OP wants a `\textwidth` node, I suggest to use `tcolorbox` which by default creates boxes with width equal to `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    colback=black, colframe=black, colupper=white, halign=center,  #1
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{mybox}
Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]