# How to simulate highlighter pen?

Tags: color

What is the best way to add a variable random height semi transparent line that overlays text in Latex? Is there a way to make its baseline variable random too?

Comment: Take a look at the package `soulpos`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959