# How to break "on line" tcolorbox when the text switch to a new line?

Tags: tcolorbox

If I use `tcolorbox` as a highlighter, how can I break the box if I switch to a new line:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\hlbox}[1][cyan]{enhanced jigsaw,on line, arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!80!black, boxsep=0pt,left=3pt,right=3pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt, boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt,breakable}

\begin{document}
The Canton System was a trade policy implemented by the Qing Dynasty in the 18th and 19th centuries that \hlbox[LimeGreen]{restricted foreign trade to the port of Canton (now Guangzhou) in southern China}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/1952) which to my understanding is not possible with `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Not posssible with tcolorbox. Have a look at lua-uL package on ctan.

Answer (score 2):

I just received an awesome solution from **muzimuchi** from Github.

We could use `soulpos` package along with `\tcbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\colorlet{ul}{red}
\newtcbox{\mybox}{
  on line,
  arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
  colback=ul!10!white, colframe=ul!50!black,
  boxsep=0pt, left=1pt, right=1pt, top=2pt, bottom=1pt,
  boxrule=0pt, bottomrule=1pt, toprule=1pt
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myul[1][red]{%
  \UseName{str_if_eq:nnF}{#1}{red}{\colorlet{ul}{#1}}
  \myul@}

\ulposdef\myul@[xoffset-start=1pt]{%
  \mybox{\vphantom{AHpgjy}\rule{\ulwidth}{0pt}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \newcolumn
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur \myul{adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor} incididunt ut labore et dolore
  \myul[green]{magna aliqua.}
\end{multicols}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc facilisis vitae massa nec cursus. Fusce faucibus gravida dolor. Cras egestas eget nulla ut consequat. Nulla eu mi at mauris feugiat ornare. Etiam a efficitur sem, et scelerisque massa. Sed ipsum justo, posuere vitae leo vitae, fermentum dictum lacus. Morbi et ipsum vel neque congue elementum. In dolor orci, hendrerit vitae sagittis sit amet, pellentesque a magna.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc facilisis vitae massa nec cursus. Fusce faucibus gravida dolor. Cras egestas eget nulla ut consequat. Nulla eu mi at mauris feugiat ornare. \myul[orange]{Etiam a efficitur sem, et scelerisque massa. Sed ipsum justo, posuere vitae leo vitae, fermentum dictum lacus.} Morbi et ipsum vel neque congue elementum. In dolor orci, hendrerit vitae sagittis sit amet, pellentesque a magna.
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]

Refer to Github at [here](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/223).