\ExplSyntaxOn problem with new paragraph
I use the below code to highlight a list of words. It works fine as long as all the text is in one paragraph and no LaTeX command such as \href is used. Is there any way to fix this problem?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn 
\tl_new:N \g_anti_keywords
\cs_new_protected:Npn \anti_add_keywords:nN #1#2
{\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }{\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_anti_keywords {{##1}{#2{##1}}}}}
% Applying the Formatting:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \anti_apply_keywords:n #1
{\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
{\str_case:nVF { ##1 } \g_anti_keywords { ##1 } ~}\tex_unskip:D}

\NewDocumentCommand \keywords { m m }{\anti_add_keywords:nN { #1 } #2}
\NewDocumentCommand \applykeywords { m }{\anti_apply_keywords:n { #1 }}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\keywords{am, are, is, isn, aren, have,has, haven,hasn, had, hadn,was, wasn, were, weren, didn,been, will, ll, being, can, would, cannot, couldn, it's, feel, felt, 
    appeared, seemed, looked}{\hl}
    
\begin{document}

\applykeywords{
The thing is the blurst. This works until all are in one parapah.

 It was a bad news. They were shocked
}
\end{document}


https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1 (not the same question, but may be of interest)

You really just need to know that + is required in \NewDocumentCommand if you want an argument to accept paragraph breaks. I sprinkled them liberally, since the underlying functions are defined to take 'long' arguments.
You should, however, name your functions and variables according to expl3 guidelines. This means they all need a 'module' name and variables should end with a type specifier. So, _tl for a token list.
If you are storing the sequence for long, you should also define your own variable e.g. \l_nakisa_tmpa_seq as other code may overwrite the contents of a common scratch variable.
xparse is not required on recent kernels.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\usepackage{parskip}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% nakisa is our 'module' name 
% g is the scope
% anti_keywords is the description (I assume)
% tl is the type
\tl_new:N \g_nakisa_anti_keywords_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nakisa_anti_add_keywords:nN #1#2
{
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
  {
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_nakisa_anti_keywords_tl
    {
      {##1}
      {#2
        {##1}
      }
    }
  }
}
% Applying the Formatting:
% nakisa for the module name
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nakisa_anti_apply_keywords:n #1
{
 % don't count on \l_tmpa_seq not getting overwritten!
 % only use where you can be sure nothing will interfere
 \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
 \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
 {
   \str_case:nVF { ##1 } \g_nakisa_anti_keywords_tl { ##1 } ~
 }
 % note that D is for Do Not Use but I don't think there's an alternative yet? (except \unskip, obviously)
 % do you need it? 
 \tex_unskip:D
}

\NewDocumentCommand \keywords { +m +m }
{
  \nakisa_anti_add_keywords:nN { #1 } #2
}
\NewDocumentCommand \applykeywords { +m }
{
  \nakisa_anti_apply_keywords:n { #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\keywords{am, are, is, isn, aren, have,has, haven,hasn, had, hadn,was, wasn, were, weren, didn,been, will, ll, being, can, would, cannot, couldn, it's, feel, felt,
appeared, seemed, looked}{\hl}

\begin{document}

\applykeywords{
  The thing is the blurst. This works until all are in one parapah.

  It was a bad news. They were shocked
}
\end{document}

[Or is anti the module? I read this like antiword software, but maybe that's just addled.]

Of course this doesn't really work when the keywords are followed by punctuation. Anyway, I suggest a few changes:

Avoid adding \tex_unskip:D by “using” a sequence instead of mapping it;
The sequence is build from the input by setting each item as the argument to the “check” function;
In order to accommodate paragraphs, the argument is declared as +m and a preliminary step is done by splitting at paragraph breaks.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\ExplSyntaxOn 

\tl_new:N \g_anti_keywords_list_tl
\seq_new:N \l__anti_keywords_text_pars_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__anti_keywords_text_pars_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l__anti_keywords_text_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__anti_keywords_text_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \anti_keywords_add:nN #1#2
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
   {
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_anti_keywords_list_tl {{##1}{#2{##1}}}
   }
 }

% Applying the Formatting:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \anti_keywords_apply:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__anti_keywords_text_pars_in_seq { \par } {#1}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__anti_keywords_text_pars_out_seq \l__anti_keywords_text_pars_in_seq
   {
    \__anti_keywords_apply_par:n {##1}
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__anti_keywords_text_pars_out_seq { \par }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__anti_keywords_apply_par:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__anti_keywords_text_in_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__anti_keywords_text_out_seq \l__anti_keywords_text_in_seq
   {
    \__anti_keywords_apply_item:n {##1}
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__anti_keywords_text_out_seq {~}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__anti_keywords_apply_item:n #1
 {
  \str_case:nVF {#1} \g_anti_keywords_list_tl {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\keywords}{ m m }
 {
  \anti_keywords_add:nN { #1 } #2
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\applykeywords} { +m }
 {
  \anti_keywords_apply:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\keywords{
  am, are, is, isn, aren, have,has, haven,hasn, had, hadn,was, wasn, were, 
  weren, didn,been, will, ll, being, can, would, cannot, couldn, it's, feel,
  felt, appeared, seemed, looked, blurst
}{\hl}

\begin{document}

\applykeywords{
  The thing is the blurst. This works until all are in one paragraph.
  It was a bad news. They were shocked
}.

\applykeywords{
  The thing is the blurst. This works until all are in one paragraph.

  It was a bad news. They were shocked
}

\end{document}

I added blurst to the keywords in order to show the problem with punctuation.

