# Recommended color for hyperlinks in a CV

Tags: hyperref, color, printing

I'm using the `hyperref` package, and I'm curious if there is a recommended color for hyperlinks. At the moment I am using `urlcolor=BlueViolet` which looks great onscreen, but when printed in b&w it looks a little grainy.

Is there a recommended color that can satisfy the criteria of looking good onscreen and one that is printable in b&w?

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/is-there-a-way-to-have-coloured-hyperref-hyperlinks-in-the-pdf-but-have-them-pr) is useful...

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks! I suspected that this might be possible, but I think it is too high risk to use as I don't know what type of pdf viewer my recipient will use.

Comment: I prefer `\definecolor{marineblue2}{rgb}{0.05,0.1,0.5}`. Similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52071/8272

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several observations: First off, if you want to go with colored hyperlinks, you should probably use one and only one color; you can do so by setting the `allcolors=<color-of-choice>` option when loading the `hyperref` package.

Second, whereas many people are used to seeing "plain blue" hyperlink targets because that's what MS Word uses for all of its hyperlink targets, in my view "blue" (at least as defined by the `color` and `xcolor` packages) tends to look too light on many screens. If you load the `xcolor` package with the `svgnames` option, you can specify `DarkBlue` and `NavyBlue`, which will still be noticeably non-black when viewed on-screen but won't stand out as prominently as other, lighter shades of blue; moreover, when printed on a B&W printer the hyperlink targets' text will appear nearly as black as ordinary text.

Third, consider using the `hrefhide` package, as illustrated in the following MWE. This package lets you instruct the printer driver to print all hyperlink targets in black regardless of the actual color(s) used in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backgroundcolour=black]{hrefhide}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=red} % use 'red' just for example's sake
\begin{document}
\hycon % turn on colored hyperlink targets
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1} 
E = mc^2\,.
\end{equation}
As stated in \autoref{eq:1}, \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, if you print the resulting document to paper, the hyperlink target "Equation 1" will be printed in black rather than in red, even on a printer that can print colors.

Answer (score 9):

I recently compiled an CV an was very happy with the `blue` theme of `moderncv`. For the printout on a non-color printer I manually loaded `\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}` before loading the theme, which turned everything to black. For a non-color printer this is the way to go. Otherwise colors will be printed as a form of gray which is not good readable in most cases. This option is very useful, because you can turn off all colors globally and don't have to redefine all of them to black.

If you get a option clash because some other package or class already loads `xcolor` then add `\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}` at the very begin of the file.

If you print your CV in color (which I actually would recommend) I would still turn the hyperlinks to a normal color or substitute them with the URL (if they aren't URLs already of course). On a print-out there is no reason to highlight URLs and doing so is actually distracting.

Comment: As I understood it, celenius is asking about what setting to use for generating a PDF that will be sent to someone else, who might view that PDF or print it out.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks, this should have been made a little clearer. In that case I would really go with the [`ocgcolorlinks` option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/is-there-a-way-to-have-coloured-hyperref-hyperlinks-in-the-pdf-but-have-them-pr) or, as already said, not highlight the hyperlinks. There is no reason to have non-URL hyperlinks in a CV and also no reason to *highlight* URLs. Only use colors for decoration bars etc. like `moderncv` does. There the color doesn't distract when printed B&W. Problem solved.

Comment: I did not know about that `xcolor` option. That's clever!

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to use b/w for printed version.  Since the links on paper are not clickable, coloring them distracts the reader and conveys a message that you really do not care about her convenience.  This is especially wrong for a CV.

Comment: I anticipate that the readers of my CV will be using either/both computer screens and paper and I thought that providing hyperlinks was more user friendly than requiring the reader to copy/paste a URL.