# Hyperlinks in CV (Resume)

Tags: hyperref, cv

I am trying to write a CV (Resume) and a cover letter in LaTeX. I wish to add hyperlinks so that I can provide easy access to more information on areas I talk about. However, I feel that it might look like I've copy-and-pasted a Wikipedia page.

Is there a way that I can make a hyperlinks obvious, but not intrusive or making the document look amateur? One idea I had was to try and make the hyperlinks disappear when the document is printed. Is that possible? Are there better methods?

Rob

Comment: Does the answer to [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/3954) do what you are looking for?

Comment: Other possibility to the one offered by @GonzaloMedina is to put the hyperlinks in footnotes, like: `We will focus on the study of LaTeX by exploring internet forums.\footnote{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}` With quite good-looking footnotes in LaTeX, this might work.

Comment: To make hyperlinks disappear while printing, use `\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}` in the preamble and in the document say `\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX.SX}`.

Comment: I prefer something like `\definecolor{marineblue2}{rgb}{0.05,0.1,0.5}` (and of course in `hypersetup`: `urlcolor=marineblue2`).

Comment: Similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33259/8272

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The technique that I use for my resume is to make the links (created using the `hyperref` package) a dark blue color. When I print the document on my black and white laser printer it looks the same as my other text. When looking at it on screen, the color difference is noticeable. (The color can be altered to make it look even more noticeable but it might possibly affect print quality.)

[image: example output]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}

\begin{document}

\Huge I like \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potatoe}{potatoes}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I do with my CV as well and I have been very happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but I think the solution is the options of the `hyperref` package. For example you can use , when printing the document, the `hidelinks` options, and set a nice color without border using `linkcolor` in combination with `colorlinks` when displaying it on a monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out this video, I explain it in there:

- [TeX Tutorial 9: Formatting & CV Design Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fJ6ZmMkOn8&feature=youtu.be)
- [TeX Tutorial 9: Formatting & CV Design Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ2EYFM3duk)

In short, you need to use the hyperref package. You can easily change the formatting on your links.

Comment: We like our answers to be self-contained, so please add the main points of your video here, or add the link as a comment to the question and delete this post.