# How to change the color of the hyperlink to mail address in moderncv class?

Tags: hyperref, color, moderncv

I am beginner in LaTeX, and experimenting with `moderncv`. I find that the hyperkink of the email is of the  same light blue color as the surrounding info, failing to make clear that it is an hyperlink. A darker blue would be ideal. I have found below that one way to change this was to make a copy (and edit the copy) of the file `moderncv.cls`, into ie my `moderncv.cls`.  I edited the two last lines below, and used the class `mymoderncv` but there is no change. I have tried the other suggestions without results either.
What is the correct procedure, if any?

[Link formatting: colors, underlines in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/link-formatting-colors-underlines-in-moderncv)

```
\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
      breaklinks,
      baseurl       = http://,
      pdfborder     = 0 0 1,
      linkcolor      = red
```

Comment: Maybe this question will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52071/12774

Comment: Not really. This works in a standard class, such as article, etc, but not in the "moderncv" class that enforces other settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just wrap your `\hypersetup` command in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`. No need to fiddle with the `.cls` file:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}       
\firstname{Mister}
\familyname{X}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=red}
}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Stuff}
\cventry{2012}{Accomplishment}{Institution}{City}{Country}{\href{mailto:mister@eggs.com}{Send me an e-mail!}}  
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to get underlined links, you can adapt the solution from [How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref):

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}       
\firstname{Mister}
\familyname{X}
\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=false,
  urlbordercolor=red,% url borders will be red
  pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}% border style will be underline of width 1pt
}
}
\begin{document}
Test
\makecvtitle

\section{Stuff}
\cventry{2012}{Accomplishment}{Institution}{City}{Country}{\href{mailto:mister@eggs.com}{Send me an e-mail!}}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. A lot more simple way...Would it be possible to make the link underlined also ?. Switching to a darker blue is better, but still not obviously an hyperlink.

Comment: @Yves: Yup, that's possible: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref

Comment: Again the moderncv settings seem to desactivate this option. Using the following has no effect... \AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{%
   colorlinks=false,% hyperlinks will be black
   linkbordercolor=red,% hyperlink borders will be red
   pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}% border style will be underline of width 1pt
 }}

Comment: @Yves: Hm, it works for me: See my edited answer.

Comment: I had the strange message: "Package hyperref Error: this color specification is not supported." However I have updated the "moderncv" package and now everything works as expected. Thanks a lot.