# Is it possible to distinguish between the soft copy and the hard copy of a pdf?

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a document with a significant difference between its hard-copy and soft-copy.

Something like some text-boxes which should be printed bold and big in the hard copy but should be hidden (or as unobtrusive as possible) in the soft-copy version.

Is it possible in latex to incorporate materials in a pdf which are printed but not displayed?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/is-there-a-way-to-have-coloured-hyperref-hyperlinks-in-the-pdf-but-have-them-pr for something for something related: you probably need to use 'optional content groups'.

Comment: Just to make sure: soft-copy = screen, hard-copy = printer?

Comment: @tohecz yes, wikipedia defines soft-copy as "the unprinted digital document file"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Update

As [Martin Schröder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73081/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-the-soft-copy-and-the-hard-copy-of-a-pdf/74224#comment184103_74224) and [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1053/alexg) pointed out, there are now three packages that support print-only content out of the box: [`ocg-p`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p), [`ocgx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) and [`ocgx2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2). The syntax to create the optional content group is the same for all of them, but `ocgx2` has the additional advantage of supporting LuaLaTeX as well:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocgx2}

\begin{document}
This text is always visible.

\begin{ocg}[printocg=always]{Hard copy}{printonly}{0}
This can only be seen if the document is printed.
\end{ocg}

This text is visible in both the soft and the hard copy.
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### Soft copy:

[image: soft copy version, with "This can only be seen if the document is printed." not displayed]

#### Hard copy:

[image: hard copy version, with all the text displayed]

---

## Original answer

This is possible using *optional content groups*, which offer the properties `ViewState` and `PrintState` to control whether the group content should be visible in the soft or in the hard copy. The following proof of concept defines an environment `printonly` for things that should only be visible when printing the document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Create optional content group dictionary for print-only content
\immediate\pdfobj{%
<<%
  /Type/OCG%
  /Name(Hard copy)%
  /Usage<<%
    /Print<<%
      /PrintState/ON%
     >>%
    /View<<%
      /ViewState/OFF%
    >>%
  >>%
>>}
\xdef\ocg@printonly{\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}

% Add OCG to resource dictionary
\immediate\pdfobj{<</OCprintonly\space\ocg@printonly\space>>}
\xdef\ocg@mapping{\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}%
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
   \pdfpageresources{%
      \the\pdfpageresources%
      /Properties \ocg@mapping%
   }%
}%
\x

% List of all optional content groups
\newcount\ocg@listocgs
\pdfobj reserveobjnum
\ocg@listocgs=\pdflastobj

% Create optional content usage dictionary
\pdfcatalog{%
/OCProperties<<%
  /OCGs \the\ocg@listocgs\space0 R\space%
  /D<<%
    /Order [\ocg@printonly\space]% if this line is removed, the OCG isn't shown in the layer toolbar of the viewer
    /OFF [\ocg@printonly\space]%
    /AS[%
      <<%
        /Event/View%
        /OCGs \the\ocg@listocgs\space0 R\space%
        /Category[/View]%
      >>%
      <<%
        /Event/Print%
        /OCGs \the\ocg@listocgs\space0 R\space%
        /Category[/Print]%
      >>%
      <<%
        /Event/Export%
        /OCGs \the\ocg@listocgs\space0 R\space%
        /Category[/Print]%
      >>%
    ]%
  >>%
>>}

% List all OCGs
\AtEndDocument{%
   \immediate\pdfobj useobjnum \ocg@listocgs {%
      [\ocg@printonly\space]%
   }%
}%

% "printonly" environment for content which should only be visible when the document is printed
\newenvironment{printonly}{%
  \pdfliteral{/OC /OCprintonly\space BDC}%
}{%
  \pdfliteral{EMC}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This text is always visible.

\begin{printonly}
This can only be seen if the document is printed.
\end{printonly}

This text is visible in both the soft and the hard copy.
\end{document}
```

The code is heavily inspired by [`ocg.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/asymptote/doc/ocg.sty), which is distributed with [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/); some information about it can be found [on texample.net](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/nov/02/creating-pdf-layers/). However it is not necessary for this example to have the package installed.

Comment: Update: The `ocg-p` package was released recently and improves on `ocg`.

Comment: Further improvement was achieved by the `ocgx` and `ocgx2` packages, the latter allowing for OCGs extending over page breaks.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: What if I want the reverse, that is, I have a line that I want to display in the soft copy but I do not want it printed on a hard copy ?  Could you show how the OCG options can reflect that ?

Comment: @me10240 You would have to change `\begin{ocg}[printocg=always]{Hard copy}{printonly}{0}` to `\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{Soft copy}{viewonly}{1}`, see the [`ocg-p` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocg-p/ocg-p.pdf#subsection.2.3) for more details.

Comment: @diabonas: I did exactly that. It shows in  soft copy all right, but when I print to file, it still shows up though. Is printing  to file different from hard copy ?

Comment: @me10240 Printing to a file should work for testing purposes, in fact the text should already disappear in the print preview (tested with Adobe Acrobat (Reader), Foxit Reader and PDF-XChange Viewer). Note that you must compile your document *twice* for the OCG to work properly, otherwise the text is always shown. If that doesn't help, your viewer probably doesn't fully support OCGs.

Comment: @diabonas: Perhaps my viewer, Evince is the problem then. Would you know of another package that works with evince too ?

Comment: @me10240 Evince (and indeed [any viewer based on the Poppler library](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34705)) has only partial OCG support, as it doesn't switch the visibility according to the information in the *usage application dictionary* (`/AS`) of the PDF.  In that case you're out of luck I'm afraid, as there is no other way to recognise when a document is being printed (well apart from JavaScript, but Evince doesn't support that either, like most non-Adobe software).