# Create PDFs that assume different colours on screen and on paper

Tags: color, pdf, printing, screen

Is there a way to make PDFs assume different colours when viewed on screen as opposed to when printed on paper?

As an example, I am using the `titlesec` package to make section labels a fancy dark blue. However, when I go on to print it, the labels look practically black. I'd like to fix this problem without having to produce a second version of my document by automatically replacing dark colors with brighter ones during printing.

Update regarding Ulrike's comment: I need this to work not just with Adobe Acrobat but other viewers as well. The suggested solution therefore does not work for me.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167846/implementing-full-page-screen-only-print-only-in-pdf/175069#175069

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is a little more elaborate than expected. I'll have to look into it later.