# Add Watermark only on print

Tags: printing, watermark

Is there a way to add a watermark to a document only when it is being physically printed?

Comment: Couldn't say how related this question might be: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167846/implementing-full-page-screen-only-print-only-in-pdf, but it sure looks related at casual glance.

Comment: Thanks Steven, it does look like related indeed. but honestly, it all went above my head :) I guess it is a lot harder than I thought.