# Setting color LaTeX generated PDF to print in black & white

Tags: pdftex, color, printing

Is it possible to let a (colored) pdf tell the printer it wants to be printed in black/white? An alternative wording of the question is: can I use latex to to set the pdf's default printing mode to b/w?

By b/w I mean black and white rather than gray.

This question is similar to [is it possible to display color only in PDF viewer, not printed page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282193/is-it-possible-to-display-color-only-in-pdf-viewer-not-printed-page) as well as to [Implementing full-page Screen-Only & Print-Only in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167846/implementing-full-page-screen-only-print-only-in-pdf/175069#175069). The key to my question is that I want to hand over a single pdf file that **by default is shown in color on screen, whilst by default gets printed in b/w**, without needing a user that configures b/w printing.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{green}{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thing for text you can use `\usepackage[monochrome]{color}`  (colour is switching off).  For images: maybe ghostscript will help ...  http://handyfloss.net/2008.09/making-a-pdf-grayscale-with-ghostscript/.  Yes always add a MWE :)

Comment: hmm, thanks, but adding [monochrome] changes the screen version to monochrome, too. That is not what I have desired. I want it to be colored on screen.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, in the Preamble:

```
\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
```

Keep in mind that anything with a color specification, even if white, will print as black.

However, the above has no effect on raster images. It only affects text, and TeX-generated drawings.