# Use black and white image for printing, color image for viewing

Tags: floats, printing

I have a color figure (image1.pdf) in a document which conveys some information nicely; however, when I print the document on a black and white printer, most of the information is lost. I have created a black and white version in Illustrator (image2.pdf, using patterns instead of colors) to replace it. I was wondering if it is possible to show the color figure, image1.pdf, while someone is viewing the document on a computer but replace it with a black and white figure, image2.pdf, when someone wants to print it?

Comment: I guess you can do it as long as you declare an option somewhere that is user-configurable.  I don't think it will happen if you are expecting this to work just by hitting CTRL+P.

Comment: Colours in PDFs are not adjustable. Perhaps one route around this is to edit the PDF afterwards and add a layer that viewers can turn on/off with the black-and-white image overlaid on top of the colour. Sending it to the printer might just print a flattened image (therefore black-and-white), but I'm really just guessing here.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169249/39222.

Comment: Choosing between two images dynamically will only really be supported (at this time) in Adobe Acrobat.  The link @cfr gives presents the solution that I came to when facing a similar (though perhaps a bit more complex) scenario.  The end solution is wrapped up perhaps a little neater at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167846/47522 .

Comment: @cslstr Good point. It doesn't work at all in Okular, for example. The second layer might as well not exist. I could only get anything to show at all in `acroread`.