# Can I have hyperlinks a different color for printing?

Tags: hyperref, links, printing

Is it possible to print hyperlinks in the same colour as the surrounding text when printing a hard copy of a PDF?

When a PDF is printed on paper I would like the links to be the same colour as the surrounding text. Is this possible?

Comment: You could specify to not print the markup, e.g. in Acrobat reader, i.e. the links should be printed in the standard textcolor then

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`hyperref` has the option `ocgcolorlinks` which does exactly what you want.

From [`hyperref`'s README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf)

> **Experimental option `ocgcolorlinks`**
>
> The idea are colored links, when viewed, but printed without colors.
>
> This new experimental option `ocgcolorlinks` uses Optional Content Groups, a feature introduced in PDF 1.5.
>
> - The option must be given for package loading:
>
>   ```
>     \usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}
>   ```
> - Main disadvantage: Links cannot be broken across lines.
>
> ....

Beware of the fact, that, however, "Links cannot be broken across lines" with this option, so, if you need this, you'd better use `colorlinks` option and print in "black and white".

Comment: [This restriction has been lifted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364143) by the `ocgx2` package, which allows for ocg colour links wrapping around line and page breaks.

Answer (score 3):

I use a compile-time switch.  That is, I have this in my file header.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Are printing a hard copy or not?
\newbool{hardcopybool}
  % set the default by uncommenting one or the other
  % \booltrue{hardcopybool} 
  \boolfalse{hardcopybool}  % the default  
% You can cause hyperlinks to be black by invoking with
%   pdflatex "\def\hardcopy{}\input{book}"
% See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1466610
\ifdefined\hardcopy 
  \booltrue{hardcopybool}
\fi
\ifbool{hardcopybool}{\typeout{!!! PRINTING HARD COPY}}{}
```

and later I have this as part of my import of *hyperref*.

```
  \usepackage[
                colorlinks=true,
                \ifbool{hardcopybool}{linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=black}{linkcolor=darkcolor,citecolor=darkcolor,filecolor=darkcolor,urlcolor=darkcolor}, % usual colors for online version of book is links are blue.  but for hard copy links are black
```

Comment: Your `\usepackage[....,` ends basically in the middle of nowhere

Answer (score 3):

It’s a pity the `ocgcolorlinks` option is fragile – that would be my ideal rather than having 2 versions of the file.

That said the solution using `\ifbool{hardcopybool}` can be simplified down to:

```
\usepackage[\ifbool{hardcopybool}{hidelinks=true}{colorlinks=true}]{hyperref}
```

with a minimal version of the `\usepackage` line. If you want to add specific colours to links, you can add those back in to the “else” part of the `\ifbool`.

Why `hidelinks=true` rather than `colorlinks=false'? Because this way you avoid ugly boxes around hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

use colorlinks=false this =nocolor. colorlinks=true this=linkcolor here blue.
for example

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,linkcolor=bleu]{hyperref}
```

nocolor and

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=bleu]{hyperref}
```

bleu