# Red box around \nameref{}

Tags: hyperref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks)

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\section{some text} \label{reftext}
.
.
\nameref{reftext}
```

Usage of `\nameref{}` creates a red box around the section header. Is it possible to replace the box with underline or just highlight the test to show that it is hyper-linked. 
When I create a TOC for sections it puts a same redbox around the section headings in TOC
thanks
Aku

Comment: Have a look at [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks).

Comment: Just use `\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}`. As this question is a duplicate it should be closed.