# email adress renders incomplete mailto in PDF

Tags: pdf, links

When I put `\email{e.xmaple@example.com}` in a LaTeX document the resulting PDF shows the email address correct, but the link points to `.xample@example.com`. de character before the dot gets left off.
How do I fix this?
(I'm a newbie at LaTeX.)

Comment: I don't know what package or class you're using that provides the `\email` command.  But you've apparently found a bug in it.  It would be good to contact the package/class developers.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang \usepackage{} was used to get \email{} or \email*{}. I'm using MiTeX/TeXNiCcenter 1.0 stable RC1 and it showed up in the suggestions.

Comment: That means you used a package, but which?  What do you have inside `\documentclass{}` and your `\usepackage{}` commands?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{mailto:e.xmaple@example.com}{\nolinkurl{e.xmaple@example.com}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `\nolinkurl` command here.  What does it do?

Comment: @Alan Munn You are right it is not needed to create the link. I just use it to ensure that the typesetting is right. Try it with and without and you will observe the difference.

Comment: @Yiannis I see. I generally like links in hrefs to match my text font, but I can see in this case why you might want a monofont there.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides Thank it works ok. I need to alter te style of this mailto-link. A turqouise box is drawn arround it. any suggestion how to get rid of that. As I said I'm a newbie.

Comment: @norbert See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks to remove the border. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: @Yiannis No thanks. If an answer is correct I acknowledge the fact. it the civil thing to do.