# Incomplete Mailto in PDF with amsart

Tags: pdf, links, amsart

When I use the `amsart` class and run LaTeX => PDF, the `email` macro produces strange output.  Namely, the PDF shows an incomplete mailto.  For example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\email{a.b@c.d}
\email{b@c.d}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In the output, the first link points to `b@c.d` and the second to `@c.d`.  Interestingly, when I run LaTeX => PS => PDF, both links are correct.  How do I fix this?

This question is similar to [email adress renders incomplete mailto in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/email-adress-renders-incomplete-mailto-in-pdf).  However, unlike in that case, I want to use the `\email` macro, or at least to simulate the behavior of `\email` in the `amsart` class (e.g., I want e-mail addresses to appear at the end of the article, etc.).

Comment: Alas and it works fine for me with pdflatex. My amsart version is `Document Class: amsart 2009/07/02 v2.20.1`. What is yours?

Comment: works fine for me, I think an update of your distribution is in order...

Comment: The .log file says, "Document Class: amsart 2009/07/02 v2.20.1", but the behavior persists.  Shall I post the .log file?

Comment: If I say `\usepackage{hyperref}` and then `\email{\href{mailto:a.b@c.d}{a.b@.c.d}}`, the `mailto:` links are created. What precisely are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to load `hyperref`, of course. Then the following works:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\email{\href{mailto:a.b@c.d}{a.b@c.d}}
\email{\href{mailto:b@c.d}{b@c.d}}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

One might redefine `\email`, but it seems overkill.