# Appearance of Links in hyperref

Tags: hyperref

I'm using the hyperref package, and have got most of it set up nicely.  I'm trying to create a contents page linking to all sections and subsections, and again have got this working.  The problem is, using the linkcolor=blue, as well as making the links in the contents page blue (which is how I want it), also makes other links within my document (i.e. figure links and equation links) blue, and I cannot work out how to decouple this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You might find [this question and its answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98528/) useful.

Comment: check this out. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98528/further-customize-color-of-hyperref-links

Answer (score 4):

Although you didn't mention it, I'm assuming you want *only* the section links to be blue and that other links (equations, figures, etc.) remain black.

You can achieve this by defining all links to be black, using the `hypersetup` command of the `hyperref` package. Then, you define a new command (`refsec`, in my example) that uses blue as a color.

Now, this does create section references in blue, but the section names on the TOC will be black. So in order to avoid this you can put the `tableofcontents` command inside a group in which you define `colorlink` to be blue (with the `hypersep` command). The redefinition will only affect elements inside the group, that is, the TOC.

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\newcommand*{\refsec}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \hypersetup{
      linkcolor=blue,
    }%
    \ref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\section{First Section}
\label{sec:first}
This is a reference to section \refsec{sec:first}. This is a reference to equation \ref{eq:answer_to_life}.

\begin{equation}
x=42
\label{eq:answer_to_life}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image: output]

Of course, you can change the color of other links simply by specifying so with the `hypersetup` command.

Hope it helps!