# coloring the page numbers in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color

I try to color the page numbers of my table of contents.

I'm using the package **hyperref** along with the options :

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=wine-stain % custom color
}
```

> Here's the output :

[image: tableofcontents]

---

The numbers remain black..

What should I do so the numbers become the same color as defined for the sections ?

I tried to `\color{wine-stain}{\tableofcontents}` but still that doesn't work since "**Contents**" is also colorized and the *subsection* numbers are remaining black.

Comment: use also  `linktocpage`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens because the links are only the titles of entries in the ToC. The page numbers themselves are not hyperlinked. Add the option

```
linktoc=all
```

to your set of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) options, which should link both the section names as well as the page number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{hyperref,xcolor}
\definecolor{wine-stain}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=wine-stain,
  linktoc=all
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}

\section{Second section}
\subsection*{An unnumbered first subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\subsection*{An unnumbered second subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection*{An unnumbered first subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\subsection*{An unnumbered second subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Adding `linktocpage` is not sufficient, since the sectional units are then not hyperlinked. Unless, of course, this is what you're after in the first place. That is, if used, it provides a mutually exclusive switch between hyperlinking in the ToC. In fact, options related to hyperlinking from the ToC include:

- `linktoc=none`: No hyperlinking in the ToC;
- `linktoc=section`: Only the section titles are hyperlinked;
- `linktoc=page`: Only the page numbers are hyperlinked;
- `linktoc=all`: Both section titles and page numbers are hyperlinked;
- `linktocpage`: Similar to `linktoc=page`

The `linktoc` key-value is undocumented, but stem from the following code in [`hyperref.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.dtx):

```
\chardef\Hy@linktoc@none=0 %
\chardef\Hy@linktoc@section=1 %
\chardef\Hy@linktoc@page=2 %
\chardef\Hy@linktoc@all=3 %
\ifHy@linktocpage
  \let\Hy@linktoc\Hy@linktoc@page
\else
  \let\Hy@linktoc\Hy@linktoc@section
\fi
\define@key{Hyp}{linktoc}{%
  \@ifundefined{Hy@linktoc@#1}{%
    \Hy@Warning{%
      Unexpected value `#1' of\MessageBreak
      option `linktoc' instead of `none',\MessageBreak
      `section', `page' or `all'%
    }%
  }{%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\Hy@linktoc
    \csname Hy@linktoc@#1\endcsname
  }%
}
```

Comment: merci, can you eventually post a link of what the \l@chapter command is used for ? For I get a bit confused of those two lines of code you wrote though I understand the patchcmd command, thanks.

Comment: @Oddant: I've updated my post since to use the (undocumented) `linktoc=all` key-value provided by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref); thereby eliminating the requirement/use of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd`. In particular, Which solution are you interested in? The older solution is still available in the [revision history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/99136/1).

Comment: really good finding~ no linktoc in the doc as said, you sure are a code-digger..

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option, using the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package and its `\cftXpagefont` family of commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{wine-stain}{orange!80!black}% just for the example

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=wine-stain % custom color
}

\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\color{wine-stain}}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\color{wine-stain}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\color{wine-stain}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the leaders (the filling dots) should alos receive color, you can also redefine the `\cftXleader` family of commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{wine-stain}{red!80!black}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=wine-stain % custom color
}

\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\color{wine-stain}}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\color{wine-stain}}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\color{wine-stain}\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\color{wine-stain}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecleader{\color{wine-stain}\cftdotfill{\cftsubsecdotsep}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that both these approaches just add color.

Answer (score 0):

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
        toclinefill=\color{teal}{\quad\dotfill},%Color of dots set here，\hypersetup{linktotoc=all} not effect to dotscolor in \usepackage{hyperref} about texlive2019
        tocraggedpagenumber=true,
        tocindent=0pt,
        tocentryformat=\color{olive}{\sffamily\fontsize{12pt}{18pt}\selectfont},%This will effect, need to set \hypersetup{colorlinks=false},otherwise, \hypersetup{linkcolor=teal} will effect to "entry of Contents", like section name, subsection name etc.
        tocpagenumberformat=\color{purple}{\fontsize{12pt}{18pt}\selectfont}%
]{chapter,section,subsection}
```

You can see [KOMA-Script: Pagenumber immediately after heading in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362280/koma-script-pagenumber-immediately-after-heading-in-table-of-contents)