# different color for section titles and pages in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using the linktoc=all option in hypersetup. I would like the chapter/section titles also clickable in my table of contents, but I want the linkcolor only applied on the page numbers in the toc and the text remain black (although clickable).

Anybody knows a simple way to do so?!

Comment: Would something like the second answer to this question work? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99130/coloring-the-page-numbers-in-the-table-of-contents

Comment: Any feedback concerning the comment from darthbith?