# Table of contents: same colour for all entries

Tags: table-of-contents

I try to 
generate a tableofcontents which I will get, but the color of the numbering+text for sections, subsections is different than the color of the pagenumber. What am I doing wrong ? Am I using the right packages, or too many packages, or not in the right order?

My code looks like :

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

% Packages required 
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{doxygen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{color}

% Font selection
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}            % 
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}  % 
\usepackage{courier}             % 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%
\usepackage{float} % for the "pageanchor"
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % Einrücken
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
% Headers & footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % making  use of the fancy-package
\pagestyle{fancy}
%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0cm}{1cm} % move the "next" text a little bit down 
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
%
\titleformat{name=\section}[hang]{\color{black}\hrule\vspace{-1cm}}{\cmssbx\color{blue}\thesection}{1.8em}{\cmssbx\color{blue}}{\cmssbx\color{blue}}  
%
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\newpage\stdsection} % start every section on a new page

%================================
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
```

[image: This_is_my_generated_ToC_currently]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99130/coloring-the-page-numbers-in-the-table-of-contents

Comment: This was very helpful to me , I now have been able to solve my issue.