# KOMA-Script: Pagenumber immediately after heading in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook, tocbasic

I want to use `scrbook` and the internal commands of KOMA-Script to typeset the table of contents and others (LoF, LoT) in a similar style as this screenshot shows:
[image]

I couldn't find any hints about it in the manual. Basic code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Blah}
\section{blah}
\end{document}
```

How to do this with left-aligned pagenumbers, adjustable spacing and being able to define a marker before the page number? (In the screenshot above it's `\cdot`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand what the desired result is. But it should all be possible with KOMA-Script version 3.20 or newer.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2016/05/10]
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  toclinefill=\quad$\cdot$,
  tocraggedpagenumber=true,
  tocindent=0pt
]{chapter,section,subsection}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Blah}
\section{blah}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

[image]

`linefill`, `raggedpagenumber`, `indent` etc. are attributes of the entry style `tocline` which is used by default for all KOMA-Script section levels.

The style `tocline` and its attributes are descriped in the section "Configuration of Entries to a Table or List of Contents" in the `tocbasic` chapter of the KOMA-Script documentation.

There and in the explanations of `\RedeclareSectionCommand` is also mentioned that these attributes prefixed by `toc` (i.e. `toclinefill`, `tocraggedpagenumber`, `tocindent`) can be used as options in `\RedeclareSectionCommand` etc.

Comment: I searched for these commands in the manuals and they're not documented there. Why not? I find this quite strange. Where did you get the information about them?

Comment: See my updated answer. I got the information really from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that the manual doesn't mention `toclinefill` or `tocraggedpagenumber` so I didn't find it by search.