# KOMA: Spacing between Page Number and Leaders in ToC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script, page-numbering

This is a follow-up question to [KOMA-Script: Pagenumber immediately after heading in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362280).

If I use the suggestion in the answer, that is

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  toclinefill=\quad$\cdot$,
  tocraggedpagenumber=true,
  tocindent=0pt
]{chapter,section,subsection}
```

then I get uneven spacing on the two sides of the dot, like this:

[image: Uneven Spacing around Dots]

How can I influence the space that comes on the right side, after the `\cdot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option `tocpagenumberbox`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2016/05/10]
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  toclinefill=\quad$\cdot$\quad,% changed
  tocraggedpagenumber=true,
  tocpagenumberbox=\tocpagenumberbox,% added
  tocindent=0pt
]{chapter,section,subsection}
\newcommand*\tocpagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{#1}}% added
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Blah}
\section{blah}
\cleardoubleoddpage
\setcounter{page}{335}
\chapter{Blah}
\section{blah}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: 26 minutes too late :)

Comment: Is it necessary to put the page numbers into a box? Is there any problem in using `tocpagenumberbox=\relax`?

Comment: `tocpagenumberbox=\relax` works at the moment, too. But from the documentation: "The command should expect exactly one argument, the page number." So I would use at least an command like `\newcommand*\tocpagenumber[1]{#1}`.