# How to have the table of contents (and the list of tables) in a different color than black in LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, color

I am trying to make the toc a color, which I have predefined, however when I try to color it, the section page numbers stay black.

I have tried multiple solutions such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99130/coloring-the-page-numbers-in-the-table-of-contents) but it just does not want to work. Here is a MWE (i decided to include all the packages I'm using in case the problem lies there):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 top=42mm,
 bottom=42mm,
 inner=35.6mm,
 outer=35.6mm
 }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear,
sorting=nty,
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Sources.bib}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MUNIblue}{RGB}{0, 0, 220}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\LARGE\color{MUNIblue}} % format
{\thechapter} % label
{1ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code

\titleformat
{\section} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\Large\color{MUNIblue}} % format
{\thesection} % label
{1ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code

\titleformat
{\subsection} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\large\color{MUNIblue}} % format
{\thesubsection} % label
{1ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code


\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} 
\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks
  \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
  \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
  \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
  \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
  \do\Y\do\Z\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%
    
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space s.\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\addperiod\space}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\nopunct}{}{}


\linespread{1}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}


{\color{MUNIblue}\tableofcontents}

{\color{MUNIblue}\listoftables} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables} \pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{11}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\justify
\blindtext


\chapter{First chapter!}
\section{And a section now!}
\blindtext
\section{Another section with a table}
\begin{table} [H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{a table!}
\begin{tabular}{r|l}
 aa & xxx \\
 aa & xxx \\
 aa & xxx \\
 aa & xxx \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
    \item \flushright{\textit{\small{Source}}}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:
[Only the chapter page numbers are colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtJRU.png)

Thank you in advance and have a wonderful day!

Comment: the default definition of `\@dottedtocline` used by section and lower levels issues a \normalcolor for the page number. You could redefine the entries with titletoc, or try `\makeatletter\xpatchcmd\@dottedtocline{\normalcolor}{}{}{\fail}\makeatother`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I' not sure I understand, can you please elaborate?

Comment: simply add the line (after loading xpatch).

Comment: Thank you very much, I have no idea what the line does, but it works! You're a lifesaver.