# Hyperref footnotes and section ref colors

Tags: hyperref, color, footnotes

I was using the `hyperref` package to link all the references within the LaTeX file, however I wanted to personalize a bit the default colors, so my preamble looks like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphics}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=Cerulean, citecolor=Cerulean}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
```

Is it possible to change also the default colors on the one hand of footnotes and on the other hand of references to sections? I could not find such command in

ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/options.pdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define a new key `footnotecolor` which allow you such a setting.

The code is:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@footnotecolor{red}
\define@key{Hyp}{footnotecolor}{%
 \HyColor@HyperrefColor{#1}\@footnotecolor%
}
\def\@footnotemark{%
    \leavevmode
    \ifhmode\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak\fi
    \stepcounter{Hfootnote}%
    \global\let\Hy@saved@currentHref\@currentHref
    \hyper@makecurrent{Hfootnote}%
    \global\let\Hy@footnote@currentHref\@currentHref
    \global\let\@currentHref\Hy@saved@currentHref
    \hyper@linkstart{footnote}{\Hy@footnote@currentHref}%
    \@makefnmark
    \hyper@linkend
    \ifhmode\spacefactor\@x@sf\fi
    \relax
  }%
\makeatother
```

After this definition you can use:

```
\hypersetup{footnotecolor=blue}
```

If you work with the package `etoolbox` or `xpatch` you can make the code clearer. Here the suggestion using `etooltbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\@footnotecolor{red}
\define@key{Hyp}{footnotecolor}{%
 \HyColor@HyperrefColor{#1}\@footnotecolor%
}
\patchcmd{\@footnotemark}{\hyper@linkstart{link}}{\hyper@linkstart{footnote}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Here an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphics}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=Cerulean, citecolor=Cerulean}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\@footnotecolor{red}
\define@key{Hyp}{footnotecolor}{%
 \HyColor@HyperrefColor{#1}\@footnotecolor%
}
\patchcmd{\@footnotemark}{\hyper@linkstart{link}}{\hyper@linkstart{footnote}}{}{}
\makeatother
\hypersetup{footnotecolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}\label{foo}
\ref{foo}\footnote{footnote}

\section{bar}\label{bar}
\ref{bar}\footnote{footnote}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: @Marco Daniel: Is it possible to remove the footnote color? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

Please look for the reference.
[options for appearance of links in hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/options-for-appearance-of-links-in-hyperref).

One can simply use linkcolor attribute to change the color of footnote.

```
 \usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=black, linkcolor=cyan]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for footnotes