# Selectively de-activate links with hyperref

Tags: hyperref

Is there a way to selectively de-activate desired links in `hyperref`?

For example, I would like to remove the footnotes from being linked and maybe also the citations. Imho it's fine if the *TOC* and the other lists (list of tables etc.) are linked, as well as the equations.

I have just read the documentation and other threads. But in my case I would like to do this globally and not just for one `ref`.

### Edit:

Another possibility would be to make the undesired parts links, but not visible (e.g. black)

Comment: For footnotes: `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`.

Comment: that works for the footnotes, thanks. But the citation remains.

Comment: Would executing `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=black}` be an acceptable to you? The link would still be there, but nobody would notice it unless the mouse happens to hover over a citation...

Comment: @Mico I tried this before, but then the links for the TOC are also gone, or at least they are not in a frame anymore.

Comment: @TomM - Are you saying that you want the hyperlinks to be rectangular frames around the words rather than colored-in words?

Comment: @Mico yes that's what I wanted. Rectangular frames for the TOC (like in the standard setting of hyperref)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention that having the links "un-noticeable", i.e., black and thus not evident as links unless the mouse happens to hover over a citation, would be an acceptable solution. You could thus try

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=black}
```

AFAICT, there's no `footnotecolor` to modify, i.e., to set to black. However, you could study the answer by @MarcoDaniel to the posting [Hyperref footnotes and section ref colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117943/5001) for a method for adding such an option. Alternatively, you could execute

```
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
```

to prevent footnote markers being made into hyperlinks.

Comment: Option `hyperfootnotes` is a package only option, the setting cannot be changed after package loading.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Thanks for catching this, I'll correct it.