# Format with Hyperref but Disable Links

Tags: hyperref, links

How can I get `hyperref` to format the link, but not actually link to anything. For instance, in the *Legend* section in the MWE below I would prefer that clicking on the links not actually attempt to open anything. But, at the same time, I need `hyperref` to do formatting of the link so that it is consistent with the rest of the document.

[image]

Using `\hypersetup{draft}` does not seem to have any effect.

### References:

- [How to disable links completely using hyperref package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53300/how-to-disable-links-completely-using-hyperref-package) shows how to disable *all* links.
- [Selectively de-activate links with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154896/selectively-de-activate-links-with-hyperref) shows how to make the links not be noticeable, but the clicking will still attempt to open the link.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}, runbordercolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \hypersetup{draft}% <-- This has no effect.
    \textbf{Legend:} Want these two links to \emph{not} be clickable
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Web links are displayed as \href{http://www.google.com}{site name} and 
        \item links to local pdf file are displayed as \href{run:foo.pdf}{PDF name}
    \end{itemize}
\endgroup
\medskip

\textbf{Main Document}\par
A good search engine: \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}

A good place for news: \href{http://www.yahoo.com}{Yahoo}

Here is an important PDF file: \href{run:foo.pdf}{My PDF}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be difficult to avoid links completly but you could use internal links:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}, runbordercolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \textbf{Legend:} Want these two links to \emph{not} be clickable
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Web links are displayed as {\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=cyan}\label{anchor1}\hyperref[anchor1]{site name}} and
        \item links to local pdf file are displayed as {\label{anchor2}\hyperref[anchor2]{PDF name}}
    \end{itemize}
\endgroup
\medskip

\textbf{Main Document}\par
A good search engine: \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}

A good place for news: \href{http://www.yahoo.com}{Yahoo}

Here is an important PDF file: \href{run:foo.pdf}{My PDF}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

The key point is `\IfBeginWith` command from [xstring](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package

It was hard to find the correct syntax for underlining using `\pdfliteral` but thanks to [this tricks](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#cancel)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}, runbordercolor=red]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newlength\mtlength

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{%
\settowidth{\mtlength}{#2}%
\def\mtl{\strip@pt\mtlength}%
\IfBeginWith{#1}{run}{%
\def\mtcolor{1 0 0 RG}}{%  red
\def\mtcolor{0 1 1 RG}}%   light blue ??!
\pdfliteral{q 1 w 1 J \mtcolor\space 0 -2 m \mtl\space -2 l S Q}#2}
\makeatother
    \textbf{Legend:} Want these two links to \emph{not} be clickable
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Web links are displayed as \href{http://www.google.com}{site name} and 
        \item links to local pdf file are displayed as \href{run:foo.pdf}{PDF name}
    \end{itemize}
\endgroup
\medskip

\textbf{Main Document}\par
A good search engine: \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}

A good place for news: \href{http://www.yahoo.com}{Yahoo}

Here is an important PDF file: \href{run:foo.pdf}{My PDF}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is the two are not always displayed the same way as the PDF viewer is the one that decides how to format the link. See [no border around hyperlinks with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210640/no-border-around-hyperlinks-with-hyperref). With your code I get [this view](http://i.imgur.com/xzNbiPT.png).  I think Ulrike Fischer's answer is probably going to be the way to go, unless the `hyperref` package provides such a feature.

Comment: what do you want a box or underline? as i noticed I am not sure I can do it but I think the hard part is gone so i can give it a try.

Comment: If I had a choice I'd choose the box for the `draft` mode, and colored text for `final` mode. However, the choice is made by the PDF viewer, not TeX. So, I don't get to choose. The requirement is that the same formatting be applied to both the link and "non-link". As this formatting is controlled by the PDF viewer,  Ulrike Fischer's is probably the best solution.

Comment: @PeterGrill Sorry but it's your fault `pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}` means that you need underlined link not boxed.

Comment: Ok, it yields a box for me with TeXShop so I did not check that carefully. However, I still want the links and "non-link" to look the same independent of the PDF viewer.