# better default colors for hyperref links

Tags: hyperref

**Update 2021** In a new driver for [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) that I'm developing as part of the "[LaTeX tagged PDF](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2020-FMi-TUB-tb129mitt-tagpdf.pdf)" project I use the colors suggested by Phelype Oleinik as default colors. All other suggestions have been added as color scheme and can be chosen with an option.

---

There have been some complaints that the default colors of `hyperref` aren't so great. So here your chance for better defaults. Suggest a new set of color. The best one will be either the default (if we dare to change it) or added through an option, e.g. `nicecolors`.

(there is also a `anchorcolor` option, but the color isn't used anywhere so I left it out).

You can enter any color you want and in what ever syntax you prefer. Adding options to [`xcolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) or loading some other package is fine too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%setup new colors
\hypersetup{
% linkcolor=
%,citecolor=
%,filecolor=
%,urlcolor=
%,menucolor=
%,runcolor=
%,linkbordercolor=
%,citebordercolor=
%,filebordercolor=
%,urlbordercolor=
%,menubordercolor=
%,runbordercolor=
}
\begin{document}
\section{hyperref colors / colorlinks}\label{sec}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color               & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkcolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citecolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, filecolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{magenta}{magenta, urlcolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menucolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, runcolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\section{hyperref colors / border }
\makeatletter\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} \def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color                    & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkbordercolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citebordercolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{teal}{teal, filebordercolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,1,1}{rgb 0,1,1, urlbordercolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menubordercolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,0.7,0.7}{rgb 0,0.7,0.7, runbordercolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite} some text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've used the following for a few books (we set file- and urlcolor to be the same): `\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}`,  `\definecolor{citecolour}{rgb}{0,0.6,0.2}`, `\definecolor{urlcolour} {rgb}{0.8,0,0.8}`, via `\hypersetup{linkcolor=linkcolour,citecolor=citecolour,filecolor=urlcolour,urlcolor=urlcolour,}`

Comment: @daleif you could make an answer. You only need to activate the linkcolor etc setting, e.g. `linkcolor= {[rgb]{0,0.2,0.6}}`

Comment: in our docs there is a reason for having them in separate names. I'll at an answer tomorrow, currently not at pc

Comment: @daleif it doesn't matter much how you enter the colors here as it is only about finding better defaults - the internal representation will be probably different anyway.

Comment: Can you make a comparison between what colors you want to modify, please? Like in columns or as you have shown in different lines. If you don't have a new set of colors then I propose to who wants to answer to do this comparison.

Comment: @manooooh If you add new colors in the hypersetup you will automatically get a comparision. And no, I don't have a suggestion myself.

Comment: Why different colour sets for colour links and bordered links?

Comment: I'd like to suggest the [henryford](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/32/a4/0e/32a40e727ff350ec0eda5347683a075e.jpg) color scheme.

Comment: @AlexG Don't ask me. We didn't setup the colors, we inheritated them.

Comment: In my experience, most readers actually strongly appreciate if only one color (usually, but not necessarily, blue) is used for *all* hyperlinks -- regardless of whether they "point" to URLs, cross-referenced items, cited publications, [footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117959/5001), or what have you. Using different colors for all hyperlink targets quickly makes one's document look like an over-decorated Christmas tree.

Comment: Urrgs.  The 80s have called: They want their EGA screens back! I might have heard a syrupy voice about eye-cancer insurances in the background, but I am not totally sure.

Comment: Citing an example of colorful refs that look good in an ebook: I've 'extracted' the colors used in Martin Kohm's ebook "KOMA-Script" and these are the values (in html-format). red: `dc143c`, green: `008000`, blue: `3953a4`

Comment: I have always used linkcolor of 0, 0, 0.6. The reason is that when it's printed, the dark blue appears black.

Comment: Well, I  think 2 colors need to be avoided.  One is red, since it's the color of warning (like in `beamer`'s `\alert` command), and green since it's too bright, and hence is very difficult to read.  It would be also great if there would be a separate color option for table of contents, since table of contents doesn't have to stand out from the surrounding text (because there is no surrounding text), while links may want to stand out some. This of course is not a criticism of the fantastic, flawlessly working  `hyperref` package.

Comment: Seconding the comment about not using red and bright green. I am also used to errors being shown in red (warnings in yellow). The bright green is not a great contrast with a white background, as it is so light. A darker green, OTOH...

Answer (score 24):

Here's a proposal (the `default color` column is (unsurprisingly) the default colour, and the `example` column is the ones I'm suggesting):

> [image]

I tried to stick to darker colours because too bright ones, especially pure [image: yellow] (`#FFFF00`), but also [image: green] (`#00FF00`) and [image: cyan] (`#00FFFF`), are terrible to read, both in PDF print. Note that in the picture above the menu colour is still a bit bright; yellow is not a good colour to put on a white background. . .

The first three colours I chose based on some colours I used for my own documents (one red, one green and one blue), and the other three I tried to pick so that they were different enough from the first ones. The border colours are the same as the text colours, except that they are mixed with white, so that the border doesn't punch you in the face when you look at it. I also changed the width of the border from `1` to `0.3`, if that's a valid option.

I also tweaked the original colours I had so that they look different enough for people with the three severe types of colour blindness (colour blindness simulated using [Color Oracle](https://colororacle.org/)):

#### Deuteranopia (green-blind):

> [image]

#### Protanopia (red-blind):

> [image]

#### Tritanopia (blue-blind):

> [image]

I also chose less bright colours so that greyscale print of documents will also be readable (though `hidelinks` is a better option in this scenario). The brightest colour (the `View Something` text in the left column) is still darker than about half of the default colours (results may vary depending on how you compute brightness).

> [image]

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\def\tmp#1#2#3{%
  \definecolor{Hy#1color}{#2}{#3}%
  \hypersetup{#1color=Hy#1color}}
\tmp{link}{HTML}{800006}
\tmp{cite}{HTML}{2E7E2A}
\tmp{file}{HTML}{131877}
\tmp{url} {HTML}{8A0087}
\tmp{menu}{HTML}{727500}
\tmp{run} {HTML}{137776}
\def\tmp#1#2{%
  \colorlet{Hy#1bordercolor}{Hy#1color#2}%
  \hypersetup{#1bordercolor=Hy#1bordercolor}}
\tmp{link}{!60!white}
\tmp{cite}{!60!white}
\tmp{file}{!60!white}
\tmp{url} {!60!white}
\tmp{menu}{!60!white}
\tmp{run} {!60!white}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{hyperref colors / colorlinks}\label{sec}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color               & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkcolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citecolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, filecolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{magenta}{magenta, urlcolor}& \url{www.latex-project.org}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menucolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, runcolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}\\\\
\end{tabular}

You can read more in section~\ref{sec} and in~\cite{cite}. Both of which
contain a~\href{example-image.pdf}{file} that can also be found at
\url{www.latex-project.org}. Such file helps you \Acrobatmenu{View}{View
Something} or, alternatively \href{run:sumatra}{run something}, which is
rather nice.

\section{hyperref colors / border }
\makeatletter\def\@pdfborder{1 1 0.3} \def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color                    & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkbordercolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citebordercolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{teal}{teal, filebordercolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,1,1}{rgb 0,1,1, urlbordercolor}& \url{www.latex-project.org}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menubordercolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,0.7,0.7}{rgb 0,0.7,0.7, runbordercolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}\\\\
\end{tabular}

You can read more in section~\ref{sec} and in~\cite{cite}. Both of which
contain a~\href{example-image.pdf}{file} that can also be found at
\url{www.latex-project.org}. Such file helps you \Acrobatmenu{View}{View
Something} or, alternatively \href{run:sumatra}{run something}, which is
rather nice.

\end{multicols}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite} some text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much better, because less hurting, colours. But the chance should be taken to unify the colour schemes for bordered and colour links.

Comment: @AlexG You mean the exact same colours for `<some>color` and `<some>bordercolor`? I always disliked how striking is the appearance of those boxes (I never use the boxes, really), so I figured a lighter shade of the same colour would be better.

Comment: Yes, same colours. If at all, less saturated colours for colour links, perhaps. They weigh heavier than borders (need more ink) by nature.

Comment: @AlexG They are the same colour (in some sense :-). The boxes (even if they weigh less than the colour links) look more intrusive to me (I'm biased though), that's why I mixed a bit with white. It doesn't look too bad if I remove the `!60!white` thing, but keep the thinner rule for the boxes...

Answer (score 19):

My personal preference would be that most link should be a uniform NavyBlue ([vote here for that option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525987/6302)).

Furthermore, the default should be `colorlinks` and not border. Borders are not easy to see and they are misrendered in Preview.app on macOS (see screenshot at end of this post). However, border don't print by default, so some may prefer them to `colorlinks`.

---

All that said, here is a proposal in which most types of links are still distinguishable. The most common types of links, i.e. internal link, and citations, are a different shade of the same colour that is currently used, so that people familiar with the meaning of these colours would not be confused. Weblinks are blue, as this is the de-fact standard on the web.

The screenshot is from Acrobat on macOS.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%setup new colors
\hypersetup{
linkcolor=BrickRed
,citecolor=Green
,filecolor=Mulberry
,urlcolor=NavyBlue
,menucolor=BrickRed
,runcolor=Mulberry
,linkbordercolor=BrickRed
,citebordercolor=Green
,filebordercolor=Mulberry
,urlbordercolor=NavyBlue
,menubordercolor=BrickRed
,runbordercolor=Mulberry
}
\begin{document}
\section{hyperref colors / colorlinks}\label{sec}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color               & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{BrickRed}{BrickRed, linkcolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{Green}{Green, citecolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{Mulberry}{Mulberry, filecolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{NavyBlue}{NavyBlue, urlcolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{BrickRed}{BrickRed, menucolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{Mulberry}{Mulberry, runcolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\subsection*{Example text}

You can read more in section~\ref{sec} and in~\cite{cite}. Both of which
contain a~\href{example-image.pdf}{file} that can also be found at
\url{www.latex-project.org}. Such file helps you \Acrobatmenu{View}{View
Something} or, alternatively \href{run:sumatra}{run something}, which is
rather nice.


\section{hyperref colors / border }
\makeatletter\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} \def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color                    & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{BrickRed}{BrickRed, linkbordercolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{Green}{Green, citebordercolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{Mulberry}{Mulberry, filebordercolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{NavyBlue}{NavyBlue, urlbordercolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{BrickRed}{BrickRed, menubordercolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{Mulberry}{Mulberry, runbordercolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\subsection*{Example text}

You can read more in section~\ref{sec} and in~\cite{cite}. Both of which
contain a~\href{example-image.pdf}{file} that can also be found at
\url{www.latex-project.org}. Such file helps you \Acrobatmenu{View}{View
Something} or, alternatively \href{run:sumatra}{run something}, which is
rather nice.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite} some text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

---

The following is what frequently happens in Preview.app on macOS when using a non-retina screen. Preview.app is one of the most common PDF viewers. Therefore, whether or not this is a bug in Preview, borders should not be the default. `colorlinks` is always better.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For voting purposes, I post a second answer in which most link types have the same colour. I chose `NavyBlue` for this because blue is the typical link colour on the web. Those link types which could be considered a security issue may have another, more alerting colour, such as `Red`. I will let others decide which link types should be highlighted this way. For this demo, I chose file, menu and run. Some may consider file links to be more akin to url links than to run links, and may therefore prefer them to be blue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%setup new colors
\hypersetup{
linkcolor=NavyBlue
,citecolor=NavyBlue
,filecolor=Red
,urlcolor=NavyBlue
,menucolor=Red
,runcolor=Red
,linkbordercolor=NavyBlue
,citebordercolor=NavyBlue
,filebordercolor=Red
,urlbordercolor=NavyBlue
,menubordercolor=Red
,runbordercolor=Red
}
\begin{document}
\section{hyperref colors / colorlinks}\label{sec}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color               & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{NavyBlue}{NavyBlue, linkcolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{NavyBlue}{NavyBlue, citecolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{Red}{Red, filecolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{NavyBlue}{NavyBlue, urlcolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{Red}{Red, menucolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{Red}{Red, runcolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\section{hyperref colors / border }
\makeatletter\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} \def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color                    & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{NavyBlue}{NavyBlue, linkbordercolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{NavyBlue}{NavyBlue, citebordercolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{Red}{Red, filebordercolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{NavyBlue}{NavyBlue, urlbordercolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{Red}{Red, menubordercolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{Red}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{Red}{Red, runbordercolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite} some text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

One could argue that the default colours do not need to distinguish between all six kinds of links. Semantically it makes sense to visually highlight the difference between *internal* links within the document, and *external* links to other files or web sites.

Here is a proposal using the popular `5-class RdBu` color scheme from [colorbrewer2.org](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=diverging&scheme=RdBu&n=5) which is both print friendly and colourblind safe. Using [tex.stackexchange.com/a/117959/24165](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117959/24165) the internal colour is also used for footnotes.

[image: hyperref colors example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\@footnotecolor{red}
\define@key{Hyp}{footnotecolor}{%
 \HyColor@HyperrefColor{#1}\@footnotecolor%
}
\patchcmd{\@footnotemark}{\hyper@linkstart{link}}{\hyper@linkstart{footnote}}{}{}
\makeatother

\definecolor{intcolor}{HTML}{CA0020}
\definecolor{extcolor}{HTML}{0571B0}
%setup new colors
\hypersetup{
linkcolor=intcolor
,citecolor=intcolor
,filecolor=extcolor
,urlcolor=extcolor
,menucolor=intcolor
,runcolor=extcolor
,linkbordercolor=intcolor
,citebordercolor=intcolor
,filebordercolor=extcolor
,urlbordercolor=extcolor
,menubordercolor=intcolor
,runbordercolor=extcolor
,footnotecolor=intcolor
}
\begin{document}
\section{hyperref colors / colorlinks}\label{sec}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color\footnote{internal color used for footnotes}               & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkcolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citecolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, filecolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{magenta}{magenta, urlcolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menucolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, runcolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\section{hyperref colors / border }
\makeatletter\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} \def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color                    & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkbordercolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citebordercolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{teal}{teal, filebordercolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,1,1}{rgb 0,1,1, urlbordercolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menubordercolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,0.7,0.7}{rgb 0,0.7,0.7, runbordercolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite} some text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I like Phelypes suggestions. Just wanted to add some that we have used for a few books (that are also available as PDF files). We always use the colorlinks option and does not differentiate between file and url.

They are either different colors or darker versions of the default, mainly chosen such that they do not disturb the reading experince.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%setup new colors
\hypersetup{
linkcolor={[rgb]{0,0.2,0.6}},
citecolor={[rgb]{0,0.6,0.2}},
filecolor={[rgb]{0.8,0,0.8}},
urlcolor={[rgb]{0.8,0,0.8}},
runcolor={[rgb]{0.8,0,0.8}},  % defaults to filecolor but it missing an
                              % expansion for this syntax
menucolor={[rgb]{0,0.2,0.6}}, % I never set or use this, so we'll see
                              % it to link color
linkbordercolor={[rgb]{0,0.2,0.6}},
citebordercolor={[rgb]{0,0.6,0.2}},
filebordercolor={[rgb]{0.8,0,0.8}},
urlbordercolor={[rgb]{0.8,0,0.8}},
runbordercolor={[rgb]{0.8,0,0.8}},
menubordercolor={[rgb]{0,0.2,0.6}}, 
}
\begin{document}
\section{hyperref colors / colorlinks}\label{sec}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color               & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkcolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citecolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, filecolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{magenta}{magenta, urlcolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menucolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, runcolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\section{hyperref colors / border }
\makeatletter\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} \def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color                    & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkbordercolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citebordercolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{teal}{teal, filebordercolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,1,1}{rgb 0,1,1, urlbordercolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menubordercolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,0.7,0.7}{rgb 0,0.7,0.7, runbordercolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite} some text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat in accordance with the ['henry ford color scheme'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525261/better-default-colors-for-hyperref-links/525987#comment1328687_525261) I suggest an even dark gray (60%) across all hyperrefs (with colorlinks as defaults as [Szabolcs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525984/172164) suggested). Additional bonuses are: No trouble with printing grayscale and no trouble with color vision deficiencies.

About the links being colored for safety (i.e. in order to tell where they lead to): most pdf-viewers should give you a heads-up if a link leads to something off your machine anyway.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{666666}
%setup new colors
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=darkgray
,citecolor=darkgray
,filecolor=darkgray
,urlcolor=darkgray
,menucolor=darkgray
,runcolor=darkgray
,linkbordercolor=darkgray
,citebordercolor=darkgray
,filebordercolor=darkgray
,urlbordercolor=darkgray
,menubordercolor=darkgray
,runbordercolor=darkgray
}
\begin{document}
\section{hyperref colors / colorlinks}\label{sec}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color               & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkcolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citecolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, filecolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor{magenta}{magenta, urlcolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menucolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor{cyan}{cyan, runcolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

In running text \ref{sec} these \cite{cite} refs shoud still be quite visible: \href{example-image.pdf}{file}. Check \url{https://www.latex-project.org/} for more information, \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something} if it helps, or even \href{run:sumatra}{run something}.

\section{hyperref colors / border }
\makeatletter\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} \def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 default color                    & example   \\\hline\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, linkbordercolor}  & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \textcolor{green}{green, citebordercolor}& \cite{cite} \\\\
 \textcolor{teal}{teal, filebordercolor} & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,1,1}{rgb 0,1,1, urlbordercolor}& \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \textcolor{red}{red, menubordercolor}  & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \textcolor[rgb]{0,0.7,0.7}{rgb 0,0.7,0.7, runbordercolor}  &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

In running text \ref{sec} these \cite{cite} refs shoud still be quite visible: \href{example-image.pdf}{file}. Check \url{https://www.latex-project.org/} for more information, \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something} if it helps, or even \href{run:sumatra}{run something}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite} some text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- I just discovered this nice effort (too late).
- This is not an answer but too complicated for a comment.
- Feel free to "Flag" and/or delete the "answer' if you dislike it.
- There is a [nice website](https://colorbrewer2.org/) that is related to the color choice topic including **colorblind safe** and **print-friendly** considerations.
- The author is apparently an expert on the topic (see [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cab38/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynthia_Brewer)).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### Update

```
% Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525261 (Ulrike's code)

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% Set 1
\definecolor{MK_One_One}{RGB}{140,81,10}
\definecolor{MK_One_Two}{RGB}{216,179,101}
\definecolor{MK_One_Three}{RGB}{246,232,195}
\definecolor{MK_One_Four}{RGB}{199,234,229}
\definecolor{MK_One_Five}{RGB}{90,180,172}
\definecolor{MK_One_Six}{RGB}{1,102,94}

%setup new colors 1
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=MK_One_One
,citecolor=MK_One_Two
,filecolor=MK_One_Three
,urlcolor= MK_One_Six
,menucolor=MK_One_Five
,runcolor=MK_One_Four
,linkbordercolor=MK_One_One
,citebordercolor=MK_One_Two
,filebordercolor=MK_One_Three
,urlbordercolor=MK_One_Six
,menubordercolor=MK_One_Five
,runbordercolor=MK_One_Four
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent
Based on \url{https://colorbrewer2.org/#type=diverging&scheme=BrBG&n=6}.

\section{Proposal 1}\label{sec}
\subsection{Colorlinks}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Type                       & Example   \\\hline\\
 \texttt{linkcolor}         & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \texttt{citecolor}         & \cite{cite} \\\\
 \texttt{filecolor}         & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \texttt{urlcolor}          & \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \texttt{menucolor}         & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \texttt{runcolor}          & \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Borders}
\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} 
\def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Type                       & Example   \\\hline\\
 \texttt{linkbordercolor}   & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \texttt{citebordercolor}   & \cite{cite} \\\\
 \texttt{filebordercolor}   & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \texttt{urlbordercolor}    & \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \texttt{menubordercolor}   & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \texttt{runbordercolor}    &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{0 0 0} 
\def\HyColor@UseColor#1{%
\ifx\relax#1\@empty
\else
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
\else
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\HyColor@@UseColor#1\@nil
\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother

% ========================================================

% Set 2
\definecolor{MK_Two_One}{RGB}{178,24,43}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Two}{RGB}{239,138,98}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Three}{RGB}{253,219,199}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Four}{RGB}{209,229,240}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Five}{RGB}{103,169,207}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Six}{RGB}{33,102,172}

%setup new colors 2
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=MK_Two_One
,citecolor=MK_Two_Two
,filecolor=MK_Two_Three
,urlcolor= MK_Two_Six
,menucolor=MK_Two_Five
,runcolor=MK_Two_Four
,linkbordercolor=MK_Two_One
,citebordercolor=MK_Two_Two
,filebordercolor=MK_Two_Three
,urlbordercolor=MK_Two_Six
,menubordercolor=MK_Two_Five
,runbordercolor=MK_Two_Four
}

\section{Proposal 2}
\subsection{Colorlinks}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Type                       & Example   \\\hline\\
 \texttt{linkcolor}         & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \texttt{citecolor}         & \cite{cite} \\\\
 \texttt{filecolor}         & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \texttt{urlcolor}          & \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \texttt{menucolor}         & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \texttt{runcolor}          & \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Borders}
\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} 
\def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Type                       & Example   \\\hline\\
 \texttt{linkbordercolor}   & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \texttt{citebordercolor}   & \cite{cite} \\\\
 \texttt{filebordercolor}   & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \texttt{urlbordercolor}    & \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \texttt{menubordercolor}   & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \texttt{runbordercolor}    &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{0 0 0} 
\def\HyColor@UseColor#1{%
\ifx\relax#1\@empty
\else
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
\else
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\HyColor@@UseColor#1\@nil
\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother

% ========================================================

% Set 3
\definecolor{MK_Three_One}{RGB}{118,42,131}
\definecolor{MK_Three_Two}{RGB}{175,141,195}
\definecolor{MK_Three_Three}{RGB}{231,212,232}
\definecolor{MK_Three_Four}{RGB}{217,240,211}
\definecolor{MK_Three_Five}{RGB}{127,191,123}
\definecolor{MK_Three_Six}{RGB}{27,120,55}

%setup new colors 3
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=MK_Three_One
,citecolor=MK_Three_Two
,filecolor=MK_Three_Three
,urlcolor= MK_Three_Six
,menucolor=MK_Three_Five
,runcolor=MK_Three_Four
,linkbordercolor=MK_Three_One
,citebordercolor=MK_Three_Two
,filebordercolor=MK_Three_Three
,urlbordercolor=MK_Three_Six
,menubordercolor=MK_Three_Five
,runbordercolor=MK_Three_Four
}

\section{Proposal 3}
\subsection{Colorlinks}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Type                       & Example   \\\hline\\
 \texttt{linkcolor}         & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \texttt{citecolor}         & \cite{cite} \\\\
 \texttt{filecolor}         & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \texttt{urlcolor}          & \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \texttt{menucolor}         & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \texttt{runcolor}          & \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Borders}
\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} 
\def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Type                       & Example   \\\hline\\
 \texttt{linkbordercolor}   & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \texttt{citebordercolor}   & \cite{cite} \\\\
 \texttt{filebordercolor}   & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \texttt{urlbordercolor}    & \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \texttt{menubordercolor}   & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \texttt{runbordercolor}    &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{0 0 0} 
\def\HyColor@UseColor#1{%
\ifx\relax#1\@empty
\else
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
\else
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\HyColor@@UseColor#1\@nil
\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother

% ========================================================

% Set 4
\definecolor{MK_Two_One}{RGB}{178,24,43}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Two}{RGB}{239,138,98}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Three}{RGB}{253,219,199}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Four}{RGB}{209,229,240}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Five}{RGB}{103,169,207}
\definecolor{MK_Two_Six}{RGB}{33,102,172}

%setup new colors 4
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=MK_Two_One
,citecolor=MK_Two_One
,filecolor=MK_Two_Two
,urlcolor= MK_Two_One
,menucolor=MK_Two_Six
,runcolor=MK_Two_Five
,linkbordercolor=MK_Two_One
,citebordercolor=MK_Two_Two
,filebordercolor=MK_Two_Three
,urlbordercolor=MK_Two_Six
,menubordercolor=MK_Two_Five
,runbordercolor=MK_Two_Four
}

\section{Proposal 4}
\subsection{Colorlinks}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Type                       & Example   \\\hline\\
 \texttt{linkcolor}         & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \texttt{citecolor}         & \cite{cite} \\\\
 \texttt{filecolor}         & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \texttt{urlcolor}          & \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \texttt{menucolor}         & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \texttt{runcolor}          & \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Borders}
\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{1 1 1} 
\def\HyColor@UseColor#1{}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Type                       & Example   \\\hline\\
 \texttt{linkbordercolor}   & \ref{sec} \\\\
 \texttt{citebordercolor}   & \cite{cite} \\\\
 \texttt{filebordercolor}   & \href{example-image.pdf}{file}\\\\
 \texttt{urlbordercolor}    & \url{https://www.latex-project.org/}\\\\
 \texttt{menubordercolor}   & \Acrobatmenu{View}{View Something}\\\\
 \texttt{runbordercolor}    &  \href{run:sumatra}{run something}
\end{tabular}

\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{0 0 0} 
\def\HyColor@UseColor#1{%
\ifx\relax#1\@empty
\else
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
\else
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\HyColor@@UseColor#1\@nil
\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite} some text
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: sorry I forgot. I choose a default, so that won't change, but I also added all suggestions as "colorscheme" options to the new hyperref driver. So if you make a concrete suggestion I will consider it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to make three proposals. Not sure how useful they are :).

Comment: Maybe it is clever to have the **same color for links, URLs, and cites** since they are typically easily distinguishable. What do u think?