# Link Color Changing in tagged pdf

Tags: luatex, tagged-pdf, lualatex-dev

Link and Text Color changing while compile TeXLive 2021 to TeXLive 2022

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tagpdf}

\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}%

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true,unicode,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0},breaklinks,bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linktoc=none, pdfview={XYZ null null 1.00}]{hyperref}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\section{Test Section}\label{sec1}

\Huge\bfseries\textcolor{blue}{Industry}

Section~\ref{sec1}

\end{document}
```

**TeXLive 2022 Output:**

[image]

**TeXLive 2021 Output:**

[image]

Comment: Er, 'yes' - what's the _issue_ here?

Comment: yes, that is by design. The new hyperref driver has other default colors, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525261/better-default-colors-for-hyperref-links. You can change with the usual keys, or switch to another colorscheme: `\hypersetup{colorscheme=primary-colors}`.  And as general advice: keep your system up-to-date if you want tagging and keep track of the state of the project.

Comment: I am using blue color (i.e. `linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue`), but in PDF showing darker in TeXLive2021 and lighter on TeXLive2022. I'm getting same color as like in TeXLive2021

When comment below lines in the `l3backend-testphase-luatex.def file`

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pdf_backend_metadata_stream:n #1
  {
    \tex_immediate:D \tex_pdfextension:D obj ~uncompressed~
      \__pdf_backend_object_write:nn {stream} {{/Type~/Metadata~/Subtype~/XML}{#1}}
  }

Comment: ah sorry I missunderstood the question. I think that this is a bug (or feature) in the acrobat reader. If one adds the pdfxid namespace it changes the color handling. See also https://github.com/latex3/pdfresources/issues/50. Imho that should be reported to adobe (disabling the xmp avoids the problem but is not something you want to do when tagging).

Comment: Thanks you. It's working fine now.