# Color Options for Appearance of Links in Hyperref

Tags: hyperref, color

Extending [this wonderfully useful post ("options for appearance of links in hyperref")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/options-for-appearance-of-links-in-hyperref), I am curious if you might list all the color options (or point me to the appropriate documentation) for `linkcolor`, `citecolor`, `filecolor`, and `urlcolor` when using the `hyperref` library?

For this, I see as examples black, gray, blue, green, magenta, and cyan.

I also see that `linkbordercolor`, `citebordercolor` and `urlbordercolor` (which control color options of the frame around links, citations, and borders when `colorlinks = false`) offer arbitrary color selection ([see documentation details](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-90003.5))

However I cannot seem to find any way to set arbitrary colors for `linkcolor`, `citecolor`, `filecolor` or `urlcolor` (e.g. [gray50](http://www.color-hex.com/color/7f7f7f), {0 0 1} or something else).

Comment: just use standard color package definition \definecolor{mycolor}... then use mycolor for any of the options

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you load the [`xcolor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package, you have access to all the color specifications this package allows; in particular, you can use the hundredths of predefined colors it provides, to the `!` modifier for mixing colors, to the `-` for complements, etc.; using `\definecolor{<name>}{<model>}{<specification>}` you can build your own colors in the desired modes and then use `<name>` in the `hyperref` setup (please refer to the package documentation for further details).

A little example showing some of the possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{F7F8E0}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{245,156,74}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=red
}

\begin{document}

\href{www.tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.sx}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=cyan!50
}
\href{www.tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.sx}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=ForestGreen% required dvipsnames optioon for xcolor
}
\href{www.tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.sx}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=myorange
}
\href{www.tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.sx}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=-myorange
}
\href{www.tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.sx}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=mycolor!75!black
}
\href{www.tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.sx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, that certainly did the trick for me. And thanks for letting me know about the package