# How to use \hyperref to change font color of citation?

Tags: hyperref

When I use hyperref with natbib, it creates a boxed link to my bibliography. Is there any way to not create the box but show the cited paper with a different color instead. For example,
[image]

Comment: `colorlinks=true` as package option?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50754/36296 for an overview