# How to disable ALL hyperlinks or at least make it all BLACK

Tags: hyperref

How do I disable hyperlinks? My references are showing as green but I don't like it. Code below:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge}

\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3.5cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

% graphics images
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{slashbox}

% 1.5 line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\onehalfspacing

% maths symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[math-style = upright]{unicode-math}

% table package
\usepackage{multirow}

% citation style
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=false,pdfpagelabels=false,hyperindex=false,pageanchor=false]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\let\Hy@linktoc\Hy@linktoc@none
\makeatother

\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\usepackage{tikz,colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\usepackage[bf,small,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

% cover
%\input{cover_report.tex}
\includepdf[pages=1]{CoverPage}

% abstract
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{abstract.tex}

% acknowledgement
\input{acknowledgements.tex}

% table of content
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{intro.tex}
\input{literature.tex}
\input{dataset.tex}
\input{module_design.tex}
\input{training.tex}
\input{results.tex}
\input{conclusion.tex}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
% references
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{fyp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You ask how to make all link black colored, right? Read your own code, pay attention to commented lines.

Comment: By the way, your examples are useless to us, because we don't have the files. They aren't needed on the other hand, so you can throw them out for a code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `allcolors=black` instead of `linkcolor=black`.

(Why do you load `hyperref` if you don't want it?)

Comment: Thanks ! I had to submit a softcopy and a hardcopy of my report. The references in green were not appearing in the printed copy and my team still wanted linked the references in softcopy.

Comment: If the final document is to be distributed on paper, it may still be handy to have working links in a personal copy (e.g. a list of figures).  Alternatively DOIs in a reference section might be set in a typewriter font, indicating that they are clickable (or indicating enough to wave the cursor over them and see it change)

Comment: If the document already uses `href` commands, you'll get a compile error if you stop loading `hyperref`.

Answer (score 23):

Package `hyperref` provides option `hidelinks` for links without optical markup.

Comment: Since it is clear what the OP's intention was, I think this should be the accepted answer, because that's the `hyperref` way of hiding links without losing the hyperlink functionality.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to (temporarily) disable `hyperref` you can use the `draft` option:

```
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
```

or

```
\hypersetup{draft}
```

In your case:

```
\usepackage[
draft,
pdfpagelabels=false,
pdfpagelabels=false,
hyperindex=false,
pageanchor=false
]{hyperref}
```

Switch to `final` if you want to enable `hyperref` again.

As mentioned before, if you don't want hyperlinks at all, don't load the package. If you simply want to change their appearance, checkout [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50754/92943).