# Change settings for hyperlinks in latex file or cls

Tags: xetex, friggeri-cv

I use the [friggeri-cv](https://gist.github.com/julien-lafont/07669e27c0a7476fc9b02f7c57271330) class for creation of CV, and it creates the entries in .tex with the following code :

```
\section{Experience}
  \begin{entrylist}
    \entry
    {Date}
    {Function}
    {Place}
    {Description}
```

The problem is when I want to put the links in description with the form
`\href{link}{nameOfLink}`, it doesn't color the name of link, so it keeps to be black like the rest of the text. Even if I change the colorlinks property in
`\hyperset`.

I guess the colors of links are defined in the .cls class, but because I have no idea what exactly I should change to owerwrite current settings and make my links colorful.

Do you have any idea to how achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the friggeri-cv uses the `hyperref` package - at least if [this version of the friggeri-cv](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/friggeri-cv-template/hmnchbfmjgqh#.WyfJ-hx9hbp) is the one you're using, you should change the `cv-style.cls` file as you already thought. 
As [previously answered on tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/options-for-appearance-of-links-in-hyperref), you should change it with `\hypersetup`. e.g. `\hypersetup{linkcolor = {red}}`

Note that this wont work if you loaded your class without colors (i.e. with the option `print`), since it redefines red as gray (it does so with the line `\colorlet{red}{gray}`).

Comment: It is never a good idea to change a class file. Makes support nearly impossible in the future.

Comment: In general I you're right, but the friggeri-cv class is no longer maintained by him and has a lot of forks, all of them with slightly different setups. So, in this case, I think that one can create is personal class starting from the friggeri-cv (one of the unofficial one since the original is no longer publicly accessible on his repo).